# Using a list of tuples in a pure function

Tags: programming, functional-style

I want to use a list of tuples within a function to make assignments.

Say I want to make assignments of the form

```
value[i,j] = val
```

What I have is a list of tuples that give the relevant indices (i,j):

```
tuples = {{i[1],j[1]},{i[1],j[2]}, ... , {i[imax],j[jmax]}}
```

What I have found is that this statement will work in Mathematica 8 :

```
Function[t, value[t[[1]], t[[2]]] = 0.] /@ tuples
```

But using slots does somehow not work:

```
value[#[[1]],#[[2]]] = 0. & /@ tuples
```

... gives an error.

Where is the mistake I am making or is there no way to do this using slots? (using `Part[#,1]` and `Part[#,2]` will not help either]?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It is good practice to check the precedence of code that is not behaving as you expect.

- One of the easiest ways to do this is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to expand the selection outward from the cursor while respecting *Mathematica* precedence.
- Converting the expression to [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm.html) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) will often reveal something about the way *Mathematica* is parsing your code.
- Explicitly parenthesize the code using `group`, supplied below.
- Wrapping the code with `HoldForm[FullForm[ . . . ]]` (or appending `// FullForm // HoldForm`)  is a robust but harder to read way to check exactly what *Mathematica* makes of your code.
- In this case syntax highlighting should also tell you that something may be wrong, but the highlighting is not entirely reliable.  (It may show errors on some correct code.)
- As a last resort if other methods fail e.g. because your code has syntax errors you can use [`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13371/121) to see how the Front End is parsing it.  Example:

  - [Infix form of PutAppend ( >>> ) does not work with variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30489/infix-form-of-putappend-does-not-work-with-variable/30490#30490)

In the image below I have converted to StandardForm and also used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to expand the selection.  You can see that *Mathematica* is parsing your `Function` as `(0. &)` and that the `Map` operation is being done *before* the `Set` operation.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A function to explicitly parenthesize code:

```
SetAttributes[group, HoldFirst]

group[expr_] := 
  Replace[
    Unevaluated[expr], 
    x : _[___] :>
      RawBoxes @ RowBox[{"(", ToBoxes @ Unevaluated @ x, ")"}],
    {0, -1}
  ];
```

Applied to your case:

```
group[
  value[#[[1]], #[[2]]] = 0. & /@ tuples
]
```

> ```
> ((value[((#1)[[1]]), ((#1)[[2]])]) = ((0. &) /@ tuples))
> ```

- This may be easier to read than the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) as it tends to expand code less.
- The output of `group` is valid input which may be used as-is or modified.

Comment: I am going to use ctrl-. more! I didn't know it's precedence-aware'that's quite useful. I mostly use ctrl-shift-B to extend my selection and check the balance at the same time.

Comment: @gwr Thanking anyone who answered is nice, but don't feel it as a being a requirement: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/thanking-users-who-answered-my-question

Answer (score 23):

This is a precedence issue: You may use

```
(value[#[[1]], #[[2]]] = 0.) & /@ tuples
```

instead (ie, explicitly indicate precedence by using brackets).

One way to see what is going on is to notice the colour of the `#` in the notebook. Or select the `&` symbol, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> repeatedly. This progressively selects larger chunks of the expression to which the currently selected expression belongs, and does so in order of precedence. You then will see that `0. & /@ tuples` is what mma sees.

You can also use

```
Trace[value[#[[1]], #[[2]]] = 0. & /@ tuples]
```

and notice that at some point mma tries to evaluate

```
value[#1[[1]], #1[[2]]] = {0., 0., 0.}
```

which is what gives the error (and is due to the precedence issue described above, as it is the result of `0.&/@tuples`; `tuples` is set to a list of three pairs in my case).

Comment: I am on the wrong side of [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/244/121) today.  I didn't know you were going to expand your answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you for discreetly telling me off :) But, in all seriousness, I simply did not think of saying anything other than "add brackets" in the beginning, and then changed my mind. It also annoys me when this happens to me.

Comment: I am not telling you off!  I am instead amused by the fact that something I supported (which I try not to do as often now) surprised me.  I started to make my post an edit to yours, but as it grew longer I decided to post it separately.