# Can a function be made to accept a variable amount of inputs?

Tags: programming, function-construction, faq

I have a function that takes two inputs and processes them for a single output.  What I need is one that can take a varying number of inputs.  and process them to a single output.  Is this possible in Mathematica?

```
 DatasetAverage[inputData_, inputData2_] := Block[{dataAvg, v, w},
   v = Length[inputData];
   w = Length[inputData2];
   If [v != w,
    Print["DatasetAverage: Data sample sizes do not match"]];
   dataAvg = Table[Mean[{inputData[[i]], inputData2[[i]]}], {i, 1, Length[inputData2]}]
 ]
```

Comment: You may want to wait for other answers before accepting.  I am sure the regulars here can offer more refined answers.

Comment: I discussed multiple-arg functions briefly in [my book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node189.html), which may add a little more info to the excellent answers you received here.

Comment: thanks @Leonid Shifrin I will review it!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes, for both named patterns and pure functions.

### Pure functions

You can see that inherently they accept multiple arguments but discard those that are not used:

```
{#} &[1, 2, 3]  (* out: {1} *)
```

The object `##`, ([`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html)), represents all arguments wrapped in [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sequence.html), e.g. `Sequence[1, 2, 3]`.  (Internally it doesn't use `Sequence` but it behaves similarly in most places.)

```
{##} &[1, 2, 3]  (* out: {1, 2, 3} *)
```

You can combine `#` and `##`, including their numbered forms:

```
{"first" -> #, "rest" -> {##2}, "all" -> {##}} &[1, 2, 3]
```

> ```
> {"first" -> 1, "rest" -> {2, 3}, "all" -> {1, 2, 3}}
> ```

### Named patterns

Using `Blank*`:

`_` ([`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html))
`__` ([`BlankSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankSequence.html))
`___` ([`BlankNullSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankNullSequence.html)):

```
f[a_, b__] := {"first" -> a, "rest" -> {b}}

f[1, 2, 3] (* out: {"first" -> 1, "rest" -> {2, 3}} *)
```

`__` requires an argument to be present while `___` does not:

```
f[1] (* out: f[1] *)

g[a_, b___] := {"first" -> a, "rest" -> {b}}

g[1] (* out: {"first" -> 1, "rest" -> {}} *)
```

Multiple variable length named patterns can be given and will by default be matched shortest first:

```
h[a_, b__, c__] := {"a" -> a, "b" -> {b}, "c" -> {c}}

h[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  (* out: {"a" -> 1, "b" -> {2}, "c" -> {3, 4, 5}} *)
```

This can be controlled with [`Shortest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Shortest.html) and [`Longest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Longest.html):

```
i[a_, Longest[b__], c__] := {"a" -> a, "b" -> {b}, "c" -> {c}}

i[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] (* out: {"a" -> 1, "b" -> {2, 3, 4}, "c" -> {5}} *)
```

See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1690/121) for an advanced use of these functions.

The `Blank*` functions are not the only way to create a variable length pattern.  You can also use [`Repeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Repeated.html) (`..`) or [`RepeatedNull`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RepeatedNull.html) (`...`):

```
j[x : _Real ..] := {x}

j[1.1, 1.2, 1.3]  (* out: {1.1, 1.2, 1.3} *)
```

These methods can be used in powerful ways such as [destructuring](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8399/121).

### Optional arguments

In addition to the variable length methods above one can make use of [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html)
 parameters with or without the use of [`Default`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html) values.  A basic example:

```
k[a_, b_: 3, c_: 5] := {a, b, c}

k[1]
k[1, 2]
k[1, 2, 3]
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 5}
>
> {1, 2, 5}
>
> {1, 2, 3}
> ```

In the example above there are two optional parameters.  By default they are filled in sequential order, meaning that in `k[1, 2]` the `2` is bound to `b`.  This also can be controlled with `Shortest` and `Longest` as noted in the section above.

In a limited way optional arguments can also be used for pure functions:

- [Is there any way to define pure functions with optional arguments?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29206/121)

`Default` can be used to set the default values for a given function, rather than specifying them as part of each function definition, but it *must* be used *before* they are defined, and it *cannot* be used to change them for existing definitions. ([Why does Default behave like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6337753))

```
Default[m, 1] = 1;
Default[m, 2] = 3;
Default[m, 3] = 5;

m[a_., b_., c_.] := {a, b, c}

m[]
m[2]
m[2, 4]
m[2, 4, 6]
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 5}
>
> {2, 3, 5}
>
> {2, 4, 5}
>
> {2, 4, 6}
> ```

Also see:

- [f[arg1, arg2,...,argN] vs. f[{arg1, arg2,...,argN}]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15749/121)
- [A function that accepts a pair or a list of pairs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26686/121)

Related Q&A's of a more advanced nature:

- [How can I create a function with "positional" or "named" optional arguments?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1567/121)
- [How to Combine Pattern Constraints and Default Values for Function Arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4937/121)
- [Can I make a default for an optional argument the value of another argument?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15718/121)
- [Function argument to default under certain condition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19488/121)
- [How can I define a Listable function only apply to a vector?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33046/121)
- [A question about two ways to use Default](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45729/121)
- [Function with zero or one arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47833/121)

Comment: Thanks very much! Looks like I will be re-writing some code to take advantage of these features!

Comment: I saw the pure functions and instantly knew who wrote the answer...

Comment: @Brett I hope that's a good thing. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, how would you call on the last argument using Pure functions? The context I have in mind is that I am going to display the product of a variable number of matrices and I want to refer to the last matrix in my code. It looks like Length[{##}] will give me the number of inputs but I am not sure how to access ##n where n is this number of inputs.

Comment: @BenAllgeier Does `Last[{##}]` do what you want or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, That does. I should have realized that. So it looks like putting `##` in a list allows you to work with `Last` and `Part`. That is what I was missing.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks for a very well explained answer. I found that one case is left unexplained: For a function like `f[x__,y__]` how would you distribute the arguments equally to both the variables `x` and `y` ?

Comment: @sinner As far as I can recall that is not available through pattern matching alone.  The closest I can think of would be `Repeated`, i.e. something like `f[x : Repeated[_, {3}], y : Repeated[_, {3}]]` but that requires a specific number of arguments.  I think one would need to do the splitting manually, e.g. `f[x__] := {{x}[[;; #]], {x}[[# + 1 ;;]]} &[Length@{x}/2]`.  (See `TakeDrop` if you use version 10.2 or later)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I found a **slightly better way** to do the same on this [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48644/how-to-pass-a-list-as-function-argument): `f[a__,b__] /; (Length@{a} == Length@{b})] := "ok"`. 
Maybe you can include this in your answer for completeness. Thanks again!

Comment: @sinner That is clever, and I feel a bit foolish for not thinking of it.  Be aware that for large numbers of arguments this may become inefficient as it is brute-force checking n/2 alignments.

Comment: Can _. be used without the default command?

Comment: @IonSme `_.` needs a matching `Default` definition set, in case the argument is omitted.  You can specify a local default using `x_: default`.  If you want the optional argument to disappear from the right hand side if it is omitted on the left, you can use something like `x : Repeated[_, {0, 1}]` or `x_ | ___`.  Perhaps also read [(44084)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44084/121).

Answer (score 10):

Just one supplementary remark regarding **conditions** on the argument list:

Functions with a variable number of arguments can be very useful, and patterns like `x__` allow you to define them easily.

But while the number of arguments may not be fixed, there may still be *restrictions* or *limits* on the allowed number. This can be enforced by using a condition as shown here:

```
f[x__] := Total@Apply[Times, Partition[{x}, 2], 2] /; EvenQ[Length[{x}]]
```

In this example, `f` is intended to form pairs from the arguments, multiply the pairs and add them. That's why there is a condition appended to the definition with `/;` - it insures that the definition is *not* used unless an even number of arguments is supplied.

If the condition isn't met, the function returns unevaluated - unless you provide *another* definition for a function with the same name with a different condition.

Comment: Related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/121

Answer (score 9):

This may be close to what you want:

```
datasetAverage[inputDataList_] :=
  If[
    Equal @@ Map[Length, inputDataList] == False,
    Print["DatasetAverage: Data sample sizes do not match"],
    Mean[inputDataList]
  ]
```

Some sample inputs:

```
In[10]:= datasetAverage[{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}]
Out[10]= {4,5,6}

datasetAverage[{{1,2,3},{4,5,6,7}}]
DatasetAverage: Data sample sizes do not match
```

**Edit**

My earlier version of `datasetAverage` was defined using `BlankSequence`, but it did not make use of the fact that it can take an unspecified number of parameters.  It is now rewritten using `Blank`.

Here is one version which uses `BlankSequence`:

```
datasetAverage2[inputDataList__] :=
  If[
    Equal @@ Map[Length, {inputDataList}] == False, 
    Print["DatasetAverage: Data sample sizes do not match"], 
    Mean[{inputDataList}]
  ]
```

The only difference is that I now enclose every occurrence of `inputDataList` in parentheses.

```
In[9]:= datasetAverage2[{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}]
Out[9]= {4,5,6}
```

Comment: Thank you!  What allows for the multiple inputs?

Comment: @RHall I used the `BlankSequence` pattern, which stands for any sequence of one or more expressions.  So now I can feed in a sequence of datasets.

Comment: I'm rather confused by your edit.  Why did you convert this to a single argument function?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I mixed up two ideas when I wrote up the answer.  The original function does not actually require the use of `BlankSequence`.  In fact, it fails if I evaluate `datasetAverage[{1,2,3},{4,5,6}]`.

Answer (score 8):

`Mean` already does what your `DataSetAverage` is expected to do. From docs [Mean > More Information](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Mean.html):

[image]

that is, `Mean` map-threads over sub-lists in its argument.

So

```
Mean[{{a, b, c}, {u, v, w}}]
```

gives

[image]

and

```
Mean[{{a, b, c}, {u, v, w, x}}]
```

throws the error

[image]

So, you can use something like

```
ClearAll[dtAvrg]; 
dtAvrg[lst__List] :=  Check[Mean[{lst}], "DatasetAverage: Data sample sizes do not match",  Mean::rectt]
```

examples:

```
 dtAvrg[{a, b, c}, {u, v, w}, {x, y, z}]
```

returns

[image]

and

```
 dtAvrg[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}]
```

gives `{4,5,6}`.

For lists with unequal lengths,

```
dtAvrg[{a, b, c}, {u, v, w}, {x, y, z, t}]
```

returns

```
Mean::rectt: Rectangular array expected at position 1 in Mean[{{a,b,c},{u,v,w},{x,y,z,t}}].
"DatasetAverage: Data sample sizes do not match"
```

If you like you can `Quiet` the error message and display your message only:

```
 Quiet@dtAvrg[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z, t}] 
 (* gives:  "DatasetAverage: Data sample sizes do not match" *)
```

Comment: Great tip Thank you!

Comment: +1 Your method is much cleaner than mine.  It is good to know about `Check` too.

Comment: @MichaelWijaya, thank you for the vote.