# Can I make a default for an optional argument the value of another argument?

Tags: function-construction, optional-arguments

I'd like to define a function with several optional arguments, some of which default to the value supplied for other arguments. For example, I'd like to be able to write something like

```
f[x_, y_: 0, z_: y] := {x, y, z}
```

and have

```
{f[1, 2], f[1]}
```

produce

```
{{1, 2, 2}, {1, 0, 0}}
```

Instead I get

```
{{1, 2, y}, {1, 0, y}}
```

Can I make a default for an optional argument the value of another argument? If not, what's the best approach for accomplishing this?

Comment: Are you an R user? I love this feature in R ... never seen it in any other language.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't easily do this with optional arguments (but see Leonid's answer for a work around), but you can use the fact that you can have multiple definitions for a given function:

```
f[x_, y_:0] := {x, y, y}
f[x_, y_, z_] := {x, y, z}
```

will do what you want.

For further use of this style you could also do this as:

```
f[x_] := {x, 0, 0}
f[x_, y_] := {x, y, y}
f[x_, y_, z_] := {x, y, z}
```

which makes the "pattern" of your function even more explicit

Answer (score 28):

Yes you can, although this is not completely trivial:

```
Module[{yy},
  f[x_, y_: 0, z_: yy] := Block[{yy = y}, {x, y, z}]
]
```

What is happening here is that I set the default to a local variable, which I then dynamically set (via `Block`) to a second argument. So,

```
{f[1,2],f[1]}

(*  {{1,2,2},{1,0,0}}  *)
```

Comment: ohhhhh didn't realize this works. Any thoughts on why Mathematica color codes the `yy` in the block red? Seems to think it is not used. Man this is soooo sweet you get the R behavior as well, you can make the default arguments expressions like `1/yy` etc. Thanks for this!

Comment: @Gabriel Well, a number of constructive uses of nested scoping constructs formally create variable collisions. Those who use that stuff know exactly how they are resolved,  but it makes sense for the highlighter to generally warn about those. In this particular case, the way it works is that `Block` does localize the special variable created by `Module`, not the top-level `yy`, so things are fine.

Comment: @Gabriel Sure, no problem :)

Comment: man thought I had this question in the bag ... then the giants come round ;-)

Comment: @Gabriel One must be careful with saying "x is impossible in Mathematica", I think most of us got into this trap at least once. Never say never :)

Comment: You can dispense with the `Module` and simply write: `g[x_, y_: 0, z_: \[FormalY]] := Block[{\[FormalY] = y}, {x, y, z}]`. It makes for cleaner looking code in the FE :)

Comment: :-) Yeah I am learning this day by day. Always happy to be wrong about such issues!

Comment: @rm-rf I dislike anything which mixes typesetting and coding, when I solve a coding problem, so also formal symbols in this context :)

Comment: I don't see how using formal symbols "pollutes" the thinking or solution... Is there some edge case where it might break?

Comment: @rm-rf Probably not, but from the point of view of language purity they are someting external. I want my code such that I would have no problem reading it from any editor, not necessarily Mathematica FrontEnd. And just typing `\[FormalY]` etc puts me off. A matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: @rm-rf: You guys are scaring me.

Comment: @rm-rf Besides, what makes you think that `\[FormalY]` has not been uprotected and assigned a value? :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin If we're going down that road, what makes you think `Module` has not been unprotected and redefined? :D Nevertheless, point taken. (I do agree with the readability in any editor part — a fact I began to appreciate only after using the WB)

Comment: @rm-rf Well, redefinition of `Module` means that anyone who does that is solely responsible for the consequences. OTOH, assigning to a formal symbol is something much more innocent. At the end, we are talking about encapsulation, and I do prefer to use some built-in means for that. `Module` was *made* for encapsulation, while formal symbols can (may be, sometimes) be *used* for it. Re: readability - yep, WB, and also I do code in other languages (C, Java, js, R), frequently or occasionally, and this also forms certain mindset which gravitates to text editors and such.

Comment: +1 for the priceless comment thread. Would +1 again for the answer if I could.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

A less elegant version than Gabriel's, and a less economic than Leonid's, using `ReplaceAll`:

```
f[x_, y_: 0, z_: Automatic] := {x, y, z /. Automatic -> y}
```

Comment: super cute :-) +1

Comment: Very nice, +1. The reason I did not go this way is that you will have to hunt down all occurrences of `z` and replace them with `z/.Automatic -> y`, and if you forget some, there isn't any easy way to see that, so for functions with more complex / larger bodies this will be harder to maintain. But for a simple function, this is quite elegant.

Comment: @Leonid yes, you are right, but I had the vision of `Options` in front of my eyes :) Of course that involves a `Module` and a local variable to replace `z` everywhere, as you have pointed out.

Answer (score 10):

Already late to the party, but here is another approach:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_, y_: Automatic] :=
    If[y === Automatic, {x, x}, {x, y}]
```

Another `Optional` trick is the following:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x : (y_) : 1] := {x, y}
```

Here the colon is used twice. Once as shorthand for `Pattern` and once as shorthand for `Optional`. This is not appropriate for you question. I just wanted to mention it.

**Edit 1:**

Since optional arguments are all about pattern matching, here a list of possible patterns and allowed syntax:

```
InputForm  | FullForm
-----------|---------
x          |  x
_*x        |  Times[Blank[], x]
(_.)*x     |  Times[Optional[Blank[]], x]
_          |  Blank[]
x*_        |  Times[x, Blank[]]
_x         |  Blank[x]
x . _      |  Dot[x, Blank[]]
_ . x      |  Dot[Blank[], x]
_.         |  Optional[Blank[]]
x*(_.)     |  Times[x, Optional[Blank[]]]
x_.        |  Optional[Pattern[x, Blank[]]]
_:x        |  Optional[Blank[], x]
x_         |  Pattern[x, Blank[]]
x:(_.)     |  Pattern[x, Optional[Blank[]]]
x /. _     |  ReplaceAll[x, Blank[]]
x /. _.    |  ReplaceAll[x, Optional[Blank[]]]
_ /. x     |  ReplaceAll[Blank[], x]
_. /. x    |  ReplaceAll[Optional[Blank[]], x]
```

**Edit 2:**

Another alternative is the following:

```
Default[f] = def;
f[x_, y_.] := Block[{def = x}, {x, y}]
```

Probably this is the best form of all I've listed here.

Answer (score 6):

I think a good way to handle this is to pass the arguments back to the function.  This is very similar to what Gabriel already proposed, but when the RHS is more complex it will be cleaner.  Unlike Leonid's method it does not rely on Symbol evaluation and will therefore work inside held constructs.

Example:

```
f[x_, y_: 0]  := f[x, y, y]
f[x_, y_, z_] := Hold[x, y, z]

f[5]

f[5, 7]
```

> ```
> Hold[5, 0, 0]
>
> Hold[5, 7, 7]
> ```

If the actual RHS were longer you can see why one would not wish rewrite it for the optional case:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] :=
  -x^3 - x^4 - x^3 y + 3 x^2 z + 3 x^3 z + 3 x^2 y z - 3 x z^2 - 3 x^2 z^2 - 
    3 x y z^2 + z^3 + x z^3 + y z^3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution: (it's kind of cheating but it is very compact and works fine)

```
f[x_, y_: 0, z_:"something"] := If[z==="something", {x, y, y}, {x,y,z}]
```

Comment: Try out `f[1, 2, a]`. I'd expect to get `{1, 2, a}`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 yeah, good point. I just edited my answer and put an extra "=" in "z=="something" so that it works in this case too.