# Make second argument same as first when only one argument passed to function

Tags: function-construction

```
Clear[f]
f[n_, k_: n] :={n, k}
f[x]
```

> {x,n}

Actually I would like to get:

> {x,x}

The following is one wrong definition, 
I'm showing that I need the argument `n` not a global variable `n` but the same to the first argument `n_`.

```
(*Clear[f]
f[n_,k_: n_]:={n,k}
f[x]*)
```

If only one argument passed to `f`, then the second argument is the same to the first argument.

So, how could I adjust the definition of `f`?

Maybe something like `Default`?

I think Kuba's answer give one example to do this.
But how to define `f` only once to get the same effect?

---

Chris Degnen's answer is one bad news.

I've tried this

```
Clear[f] f[n0_, k0_: 5] := Module[{n = n0, k = k0}, If[k == 5, {n, k = n0},{n, k}]]
f[x]
```

> {x,x}

Good thing is it works well for numerical values.

```
f[x, 10]
```

> {x,10}

Bad thing is it works badly for `y`

```
f[x, y]
```

> If[y==5,{n$37693,k$37693=x},{n$37693,k$37693}]

Comment: I have responded to Your edit.

Comment: @Kuba ah, it works, I tried one number 5, so I used `==`, next time I'll use `SameQ` firstly. Stefan have gave one answer.

Answer (score 6):

I would use something called overloading (but I'm not sure about the name)

```
f[n_, k_] := {n, k}
f[x_] := f[x, x]
```

so:

```
f[x]
f[x, 5]
```

> {x, x}
>
> {x, 5}

---

**Edit**

Reffering to Your last edit. I would use `===` for testing and `y_:"Default"` insted of `y_:5` (You may need `5` someday :)).

It will work but remember that this is some kind of limitation. Now You are working on values, not the arguments as You may sometimes want to. If it is a problem depends on what You are going to do with this function. I think it is going to suit Your needs in most cases.

Comment: Your answer is good, I wonder if it could be done by one definition of `f`.

Answer (score 5):

This has been discussed before. Here is how:

```
Module[{def}, f[n_, k_: def] := Block[{def = n}, {n, k}]]
```

The `Module` is needed to make sure that `def` is not changeable from the top level. Examples:

```
f[x, y]

(* {x, y} *)

f[x]

(* {x, x} *)
```

Comment: saw your answer when i already updated mine...sorry about that. let's see it as an alternative to your probably best answer.

Comment: ah, good to learn that, is there some links/keywords about some the former discussions?

Comment: @HyperGroups For example, [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15718/can-i-make-a-default-for-an-optional-argument-the-value-of-another-argument/15720#15720). In fact, your question is a duplicate of that one, so I will leave a comment below it and vote to close.

Comment: ok, no problem, good to know about some duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

Roman Maeder addresses this in Programming in Mathematica (3rd ed.), page 21. Regarding *default values*, he writes:

```
f[ x_, y_:17 ] := {x, y}
```

> "Please note that the default value cannot depend on the other
>   parameters (`x`, for example).  It is evaluated when the rule is
>   given, rather than later on when the rule is used.  In more
>   complicated cases, it is better to give a second rule that computes
>   the default value and then calls the other rule."

... as demonstrated by Kuba.

Comment: good to know about that.

Comment: This is not quite true. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Already late to the party, but here is another approach:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_, y_: Automatic] :=
    If[y === Automatic, {x, x}, {x, y}]
```

Another `Optional` trick is the following:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x : (y_) : 1] := {x, y}
```

Here the colon is used twice. Once as shorthand for `Pattern` and once as shorthand for `Optional`. This is not appropriate for you question. I just wanted to mention it.

**Edit 1:**

Since optional arguments are all about pattern matching, here a list of possible patterns and allowed syntax:

```
InputForm  | FullForm
-----------|---------
x          |  x
_*x        |  Times[Blank[], x]
(_.)*x     |  Times[Optional[Blank[]], x]
_          |  Blank[]
x*_        |  Times[x, Blank[]]
_x         |  Blank[x]
x . _      |  Dot[x, Blank[]]
_ . x      |  Dot[Blank[], x]
_.         |  Optional[Blank[]]
x*(_.)     |  Times[x, Optional[Blank[]]]
x_.        |  Optional[Pattern[x, Blank[]]]
_:x        |  Optional[Blank[], x]
x_         |  Pattern[x, Blank[]]
x:(_.)     |  Pattern[x, Optional[Blank[]]]
x /. _     |  ReplaceAll[x, Blank[]]
x /. _.    |  ReplaceAll[x, Optional[Blank[]]]
_ /. x     |  ReplaceAll[Blank[], x]
_. /. x    |  ReplaceAll[Optional[Blank[]], x]
```

**Edit 2:**

Another alternative is the following:

```
Default[f] = def;
f[x_, y_.] := Block[{def = x}, {x, y}]
```

Probably this is the best form of all I've listed here.

Comment: nice, why the second trick does not generate the right result for `f[x,y]` as `{x,y}`?

Comment: the two variables x, y represent the same pattern. please have a look at this, which makes that more obvious: y : (y_) : 1 // FullForm. if you want f[x, y] correctly evaluated you have to overload f accordingly.

Comment: What about when somebody calls `f[x,Automatic]`? :)

Comment: @CoreyKelly result is {x, x}. what are you asking for?

Comment: Well, two inputs were passed. Shouldn't the output be `{x,Automatic}` in that case?

Comment: nope. if y === Automatic => x...do i oversee here something?

Comment: I realize what it actually returns. The OP wanted a function that returns the two input variables: `f[x,y] = {x,y}` but in this (edge) case, `y=Automatic` and the return value isn't `{x,y}`.

Comment: ah! now i get it. yes :) ... ok. i cannot fight machiavelli. maybe an answer to this "edge"-case is: well Automatic chose automatically x, since y was set to Automatic which chooses x automatically, if y is Automatic. ;)

Comment: ah, nice in Edit 2.