# Optional arguments with lists as function parameter

Tags: functions, function-construction, optional-arguments

I'm developing a function `f` which should support optional arguments `{x_, y_}` in list form. A simple example looks like this:

```
f[{x_, y_}] := {x, y}
```

How can I set default values for the list argument `{x_, y_}`? My first attempt was

```
f[{x_:1, y_:2}] := {x, y}
```

which matches `f[{}]` and correctly returns `{1, 2}` but which does not match `f[]`.

How can I define the function `f` so that `f[]` gives the desired default values?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html

Comment: add `f[] = f[{}]`  later, it this ok?

Comment: This seems not to be a nice solution. There are many internal MMA functions like `ImageTake` which use optinal and default arguments in list form. Basically I want to implement the same functionality regarding optional arguments as in  `ImageTake`, see the documentation.

Comment: @Kuba Sorry for being unprecise. I'm just wondering if your solution is the "official" way to deal with optional list arguments like in `ImageTake`. I also tried `f[args:{x_, y_}:{1,2}] := {x, y}`which seems to work. However, I'm not sure if understand it the right way...

Comment: @Robinaut Use ``Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];`` and evaluate `PrintDefinitions@Cells`, as you can see, WRI is not trying to put everything in one pattern either. It is not handy nor readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sorry for being unprecise. I'm just wondering if your solution is the "official" way to deal with optional list arguments like in `ImageTake`. I also tried `f[args:{x_, y_}:{1,2}] := {x, y}`which seems to work. However, I'm not sure if understand it the right way...

I do not believe I have seen a guideline or even a standard practice for this particular case.  I quite like Kuba's solution and I often make use of that method, e.g.: [Can I make a default for an optional argument the value of another argument?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15718/can-i-make-a-default-for-an-optional-argument-the-value-of-another-argument/72995#72995)

You chose `ImageTake` as a model.  For this function there is no need for the optional behavior that you describe as the syntax is already handled by [`Take`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Take.html).  Note:

[image]

This syntax is valid for each argument of `ImageTake` (after the first) just as it is for `Take`.  Therefore a trivial reimplementation is:

```
myImageTake[i : _Image | _Image3D, spec__] := 
  Head[i][Take[ImageData[i], spec], ColorSpace -> ImageColorSpace[i]]
```

Test:

```
img = Import["http://cdn.sstatic.net/mathematica/img/logo@2.png"]  (* site logo *)

myImageTake[img, -66, {30, 120}]
ImageTake[img, -66, {30, 120}]
```

[image]

```
img3D = ExampleData[{"TestImage3D", "CThead"}];

myImageTake[img3D, -20, {80, 180}, 120]
ImageTake[img3D, -20, {80, 180}, 120]
```

[image]

If I wanted tighter control of the input than `spec__` I would use something like:

```
p1 = (All | _Integer | {Repeated[_Integer, {1, 3}]})?(FreeQ[#, 0] &);

ClearAll[myImageTake]

myImageTake[i : _Image | _Image3D, spec : p1 ..] /; 
  Length[{spec}] <= Length@ImageDimensions[i] := 
    Head[i][Take[ImageData[i], spec], ColorSpace -> ImageColorSpace[i]]
```

This example may be a bit too specific but it is the one that you gave.  For other examples the pattern you found (`args:{x_, y_}:{1,2}`) or the method of passing arguments back to the function (Kuba's answer and my linked post above) may be more appropriate.  If you give another example or model function I shall try to address that as well.

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways to achieve this, I'd probably do something simple like

```
f[] = f[{}] 
(*set or set delayed, depends of context*)
```

---

But you can also do something more fancy, although it is not compact enough for me to like it :P

```
Default[f] = {};
f[Optional@{x_: 1, y_: 2}] := {x, y}

f[]
f[{}]
```

> ```
> {1, 2}
> {1, 2}
> ```