# Can one specify a "computed optional value"?

Tags: function-construction

I would like to write a function with an optional argument, which if absent should not be a default value, but rather a computed value. What I mean is the following [warning this code does not work, it's just for a descriptive purpose]

```
f[var1_, var2_ : g[var1] ] := etc...
```

where `g` is some function. So far I have tried using a silly default value for var2 and an if statement:

```
f[var1_, var2_ : 123456789] := If[ var2 == 123456789 , var2 = g[var1] , etc...]
```

which works, but is ugly...

Comment: I kind of like your approach, actually, but perhaps to be safe, your "default" value could be something that no chance of being an input to `f`, like, say, `f[var1_, var2_ : "Pileated"] := ... `.

Comment: lol, yeah one could go crazy on that one

Comment: Closely related, if not a duplicate: [Can I make a default for an optional argument the value of another argument?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15718/can-i-make-a-default-for-an-optional-argument-the-value-of-another-argument)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way is simply to define the two-argument case,

```
f[var1_, var2_] := ...
```

and then the one-argument case as

```
f[var1_] := f[var1, g[var1]]
```

Of course, if things get fancy, this sort of scheme will stretch but it can eventually break. For more flexible uses, see Leonid Shiffrin's answer to [this similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15718/can-i-make-a-default-for-an-optional-argument-the-value-of-another-argument).

Comment: Oh yeah, this is much prettier! Thanks