# How to define function that variable is optional?

Tags: functions, variable-definitions

I want to define some function that I can do something for the troubleshooting purpose.

```
kk[x_, L_] := Module[{x1, x2},
x1 = "x is too big"; x2 = "x is too small" ;
If[L == 1, If[x>1,Print[x1],Print[x2]]];
Print[x];
]
```

If I plug in L value in the function, then I will get the message. However, if I do not plug in L, then This function will not work because I did not define L.

I want to make this function work no matter there is L or not. So I want to make L optional. Is it possible for me to define such thing in Mathamtica?

Comment: Yes, you can define `kk[x_, L_:1] := . . .` to give parameter `L` the default value of `1`.  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionalAndDefaultArguments.html

Comment: Recommended additional reading, once you have absorbed the tutorial linked above:  [(4937)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4937/121),
[(6588)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6588/121),
[(15718)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15718/121),
[(1567)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1567/121),
[(108636)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108636/121)

Comment: `Print` is a very limited form of output. Recommend that you use something along the lines of `kk[x_, L_:1] := Module[{x1, x2}, x1 = "x is too big"; x2 = "x is too small"; {If[L == 1, If[x > 1, x1, x2]], x}]` then you could use `kk[.5] // Column`