# Optional argument in Set Function

Tags: functions, optional-arguments

Optional arguments can be defined in SetDelayed (:=) Functions (see f1 below and [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15718/can-i-make-a-default-for-an-optional-argument-the-value-of-another-argument)). However, how can one accomplish this in Set (=) Functions (see f2 and f3 below)?

```
f1[x_:0]:=x
f1[4] (* 4 *)
f1[] (* 0 *)
f2=Function[{x},x]
f2[4] (* 4 *)
f2[] (* Function:fpct:Too many parameters in {x} to be filled from Function[{x},x][]. *)
f3=Function[{x:0},x] (* Function:flpar:Parameter specification {x:0} in Function[{x:0},x] should be a symbol or a list of symbols. *)
```

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html

Comment: @egwenesedai That does not help.

Comment: ok, noticed that this may not be a good option here. I would avoid `Set` and use the proved-to-be-working `SetDelayed` unless there's a strong reason for not using that. Found a possible duplicate here, notice that answer still uses `:>` (`RuleDelayed`)

Comment: Yes, that's a duplicate, thanks. Unfortunately, not a satisfying answer...