# Function pattern to support listed and non-listed arguments

Tags: functions, function-construction, argument-patterns

I often want to write functions that take as an argument either a) a rule or b) a list of rules. As an example, when using `Replace` with just one rule, it does not matter whether you give it as a list or not:

```
Replace[Range[10], 7->"seven", {1}]
Replace[Range[10], {7->"seven"}, {1}]
```

will both work as expected.

Now, if I wanted to set this up, I would use the listed form throughout the function body, and add a second function pattern to actually rewrite the non-listed Rule into a List:

```
Replace[expr_, rules_Rule, levelspec_] := Replace[expr, {rules}, levelspec]
Replace[expr_, rules_List, levelspec_] := the function body...
```

Is there a way to write a pattern which matches both forms and returns the listed one?

It is, of course, not too hard to write the function body in a way that it supports both forms. But actually I would like to have it done in the pattern already, so I will not have to take special care of it and can easily extend existing functions to support this feature.

Comment: I use the same approach that you describe.  I think it's the best.  Of course it's very difficult to prove that something is *not* possible, so let's wait :-)  It *is* possible to use a single pattern as in `_Rule | {__Rule}` but this will shift handling the list-vs-nonlist problem elsewhere, so it doesn't simplify things.  I prefer the solution you describe, i.e. `f[r_Rule] := f[{r}]`.

Comment: Well, when I try to use x_Rule|x__Rule, I get `attern::patv: Name x used for both fixed and variable length patterns.` as an error.

Comment: Exactly.  You need to use `r: (_Rule | {__Rule})` then in the body of your function check if `r` is a list of rules or a single rule.  This *is* a single pattern, but it makes things more complicated.  This is why I think that your solution is the best alternative.

Comment: You may be able to use @Szabolcs's pattern and just wrap it with a list by default if you are using the rules for pattern matching. Mathematica will unwrap lists of rules in most situations, but not always. Try: `Range@10 /. {7 -> "seven", 8 -> "eight"}` and `Range@10 /. {{7 -> "seven", 8 -> "eight"}}` and `Range@10 /. {{{7 -> "seven", 8 -> "eight"}}}` for example.

Comment: The `patv` message is not an error. It is simply a warning. The definition is still made as requested and you can choose to ignore the message if you wish.

Comment: Right, I see. So then I will have all rules Sequenced and can use `{rules}` throughout the function body. Any way to have the rules always listed (so that `rules` always is a list,  no matter whether it was given as `_Rule` or as `{__Rules}`)?

Comment: @OleksandrR. Oops, you're right.  I looked at the message and stopped there.  Do you want to post it as an answer?  `f[r_Rule | {r__Rule}] := {r}`.

Comment: I feel that this question is a duplicate of: [(26686)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26686) -- if anyone disagrees please say so.

Comment: It seems I was planning to close this but I forgot.  Since the answers here are apparently satisfactory I shall do that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are specifically interested in pattern matching rather than functional equivalents such as the one presented by eldo here is an additional answer.

Szabolcs already gave my preferred solution, which is to use [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Alternatives.html), though he did not recommend it.  Nevertheless I do.  As complete code for reference:

```
foo[rules : _Rule | {__Rule}] := bar[rules]

foo[1 -> 2]

foo[{1 -> 2, "a" -> "b"}]
```

> ```
> bar[1 -> 2]
>
> bar[{1 -> 2, "a" -> "b"}]
> ```

You can usually use this as-is because as you note System functions are designed to accept both forms.  If for whatever reason you need to "use the listed form throughout the function body" it's as simple as:

```
Off[Pattern::patv]

ClearAll[foo]
foo[rules_Rule | {rules___Rule}] := bar[{rules}]

foo[1 -> 2]

foo[{1 -> 2, "a" -> "b"}]
```

> ```
> bar[{1 -> 2}]
>
> bar[{1 -> 2, "a" -> "b"}]
> ```

Note that I turned off the `Pattern::patv` Message.  As Oleksandr correctly notes that Message does *not* indicate an error but merely serves to indicate a *possible* mistake; I see it as little more than "training wheels" for new users.  Once you understand what it is warning against I suggest you turn it off as it may otherwise keep you from using *Mathematica* patterns to their full potential.

A final note: don't forget to allow for `RuleDelayed` rules in your function definitions if you wish to make them general.

---

Recommended reading:

- [Alternatives pattern in a function definition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44081/alternatives-pattern-in-a-function-definition/44084#44084) ("vanishing patterns")
- [Alternatives ordering affects pattern matching in Cases?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51463/121)

---

A simpler question of the same type:

- [f[arg1, arg2,...,argN] vs. f[{arg1, arg2,...,argN}]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15749/121)

Comment: Good explanation, thank you!

Comment: @Theo You're welcome.  Thanks for the Accept.

Comment: @Theo I added links to a couple of earlier answers of mine that I think you should read as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
replace[expr_, levelspec_, rules__] := Replace[expr, List @ rules, levelspec]

replace[Range @ 10, {1}, 7 -> "seven"]
replace[Range @ 10, {1}, 7 -> {"seven"}]

replace[Range @ 10, {1}, 7 -> "seven", 8 -> "eight"]
replace[Range @ 10, {1}, {7 -> "seven", 8 -> "eight"}]
```

All give the expected results.

Comment: I didn't edit your bracketing. That edit was made by YOU. Look at the edit history.

Comment: @m_goldberg - So sorry, you're right

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. However, your code does not address the essential part of the question, i.e. how to support listed and non-listed arguments in a simple manner.