# Safe way to put a pattern on the right hand side of a rule

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, replacement, warning-messages

I'm interested in creating a function or rule that generates its own set of rules. For instance, it would take as an input the expression `h[m, n]` and the indices `m` and `n`, and output the rule:

```
h[m_, n_] :> h[m, n]
```

What I have is:

```
makeLHSReplacementRule[expr_, {m_,n_}] := 
  ((expr /. m -> head[m] /. n -> head[n]) /. head[a_] :> head[a_]) /. head[A_] :> A

replacementRule[expr_, {m_, n_}] := makeLHSReplacementRule[expr, {m, n}] :> expr  

replacementRule[h[m, n], {m, n}]
```

The output is actually exactly what I want, which is:

```
h[m_, n_] :> h[m, n]
```

But I get an error message complaining about my having the pattern `a_` appearing on the right hand side of a rule. This is making me think it might not be safe to do this (it is also very annoying, as I need to run this function many times). Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Replace `head[a_] :> head[a_]` with `head[a_] :> With[{b = a}, head[b_]]`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`RuleDelayed::rhs` is not an *error* message but rather a *warning* message.  This is an important distinction.  If you know what you are doing the message can be safely ignored.  This is also the case with `Pattern::patv`.<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26690/121)[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/52258/121)</sup>

I would say that your method as written is not safe however for a different reason: it evaluates the Symbols `m` and `n` which means your code breaks if these are defined.  Please consider this as an alternative:

```
SetAttributes[replacementRule, HoldAll]

replacementRule[expr_, {var__Symbol}] :=
 (Unevaluated[expr] /.
    Thread[Thread @ HoldPattern @ {var} -> Thread @ Pattern[{var}, _]]) :> expr
```

Test:

```
m := Print["fail!"];

replacementRule[h[m, n], {m, n}]
```

> ```
> h[m_, n_] :> h[m, n]
> ```

Or instead using [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) to guard against evaluation:

```
ClearAll[replacementRule]

SetAttributes[replacementRule, HoldAll]

replacementRule[expr_, var : {__Symbol}] :=
  Block[var,
    Unevaluated[expr] /. Thread[var -> (Pattern[#, _] & /@ var)]
  ] :> expr
```

---

### Further thoughts

Both examples above manage to avoid `RuleDelayed::rhs` by not having an explicit `var_` in the body of the definition, but that should not be taken to mean that this is actually superior to methods that *do* trigger the warning.

Here is a third approach that is more similar to your original method:

```
ClearAll[replacementRule]
Attributes[replacementRule] = {HoldAll};

replacementRule[expr_, {var__Symbol}] :=
  (Unevaluated[expr] /. x : HoldPattern[Alternatives[var]] :> x_) :> expr
```

This is somewhat more streamlined than my first method with repeated use of [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) but it throws a warning message when used:

```
replacementRule[h[m, n], {m, n}]
```

> RuleDelayed::rhs: Pattern x\$_ appears on the right-hand side of rule x\$:HoldPattern[m|n]:>x\$_. >>
>
> ```
> h[m_, n_] :> h[m, n]
> ```

(The appearance of `x$` comes from the automatic renaming that takes place in nested scoping constructs of which `RuleDelayed` is one, despite its not being specifically advertised as such.  I started [an answer which Leonid Shifrin greatly expanded](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20776/121) regarding this that you should eventually read.)

It would in my opinion be entirely acceptable to suppress that warning with [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html):

```
ClearAll[replacementRule]
Attributes[replacementRule] = {HoldAll};

replacementRule[expr_, {var__Symbol}] := 
  Quiet[
    Unevaluated[expr] /. x : HoldPattern[Alternatives[var]] :> x_, 
    RuleDelayed::rhs
  ] :> expr
```

In retrospect I think I prefer this to my earlier recommendation.

Comment: Thanks very much for the advice!

Comment: @pploops You're welcome.  Let me know if you have any questions about my sometimes opaque code.

Comment: Regarding your final method, could you explain what is the purpose of HoldPattern - what does it safeguard again precisely? Also is the use of Symbol in var__Symbol just good practice? Thanks so much for answering these questions!

Comment: @pploops `HoldPattern`, when combined with `HoldAll` for `replacementRule`, prevents the Symbols like `m` and `n` from evaluating.  I used `m := Print["fail!"];` earlier in the post to illustrate this.  In your application this may not matter but it is better to think about such things if you want your code to be reusable.  This is not without consequence however as due to `HoldAll` one cannot do e.g. `foo = h[m, n]` and then `replacementRule[foo, {m, n}]`.  Possibly a better choice would be `HoldRest` assuming that head `h` has a Hold attribute itself in which case this example would work.

Comment: @pploops I did not want to complicate my answer further with this but am happy to describe it further if requested.  My use of `__Symbol` is what I would consider good practice.  While it is not strictly necessary it will catch problems that might otherwise be confusing.