# Module inside Module. Conflict of names in arguments

Tags: function-construction, scoping, language-design

I have a module which calls number of other smaller helper modules. But those other helper modules are not used by another module, so there is no needed to have them in global context. So I wanted to move them to be inside the main module which is the only one that uses them to help improve the code. But I found two main issue when doing this.

### First issue conflict in names of argument input

If the helper function uses the same input argument name, as in the main module, error is generated when moving the helper module inside it.

Here is a MWE. This is the before layout of the code

```
boo[a_]:=Module[{b=5}, b+a ];
foo[a_]:=Module[{}, boo[a]];
```

Now `foo[3]` returns `8` and works.  Now moving `boo` inside `foo` for better `encapulation` since `boo[]` is only needed by `foo`, the layout becomes

```
foo[a_]:=Module[{boo},
     boo[a_]:=Module[{b=5}, b+a];  (*boo now local*)
     boo[a]
];
```

But M does not like the above

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can ask, why not simply rename the argument(s) of boo and rename all references inside the `boo` code to the new name(s)? Yes, in this simple example I can change the code and do

```
foo[a_]:=Module[{boo},
     boo[aa_]:=Module[{b=5}, b+aa];
     boo[a]
];
foo[3]
(* 8 *)
```

### Second issue helper function uses same local variable name as input argument of main module

If the helper function happened to have local variable in it, which has same name as the input argument of the main module, then also an error is generated. Here is an example. The before, which works

```
boo[aa_]:=Module[{b=5,a=3},b+aa+a];
foo[a_]:=Module[{},boo[a]]
foo[3]
(* 11 *)
```

The after layout

```
foo[a_]:=Module[{boo},
    boo[aa_]:=Module[{b=5,a=3},
              b+aa+a
    ];
    boo[a]
];
foo[3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above examples shows that it is not easy to do what I wanted, without careful code rewrite all the time due to these conflicts.

The above are simple examples. The code I have is much larger which means I have to go make number of changes, renaming variables all over the place each time. So I end up now having many smaller functions all in global space, even though many of them can be put inside the Modules that really uses them.

Is there a trick to bypass this problem? Is there a better way do the above? Would workbench help in this?

Maple have no problem using the same setup

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

references
[safe-way-to-put-a-pattern-on-the-right-hand-side-of-a-rule](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121845/safe-way-to-put-a-pattern-on-the-right-hand-side-of-a-rule)
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Rule/rhs.html

Comment: Why not just create a package? Also, I think using SetDelayed in this way inside of a module is better avoided. For your example, if `boo` doesn't depend on the arguments to `foo`, then `foo` has to work harder because it defines `boo` every time it is called, instead of having `boo` defined once. Also, if `boo` is ever left unevaluated, either in the output of `foo` or in a side effect, then `boo` will never get removed, causing a memory leak. Finally, it is much harder to debug `boo` when it is defined in a Module.

Comment: @CarlWoll how is using a package will make it easier to move the helper functions inside the module? Will not the same issue be there, but now everything is inside a new context?  My main goal was to see if I can have small helper functions inside the module that uses them, not outside. So if I have 2 modules, each uses different helper functions, and there is no shared helper function, I wanted to move these inside.  I am not following what you say about memory leak and having to define `boo` each time parent module is called. Too advanced for me to understand now. Thanks,.

Comment: What is the problem with having helper functions outside the module? If you don't like having the helper functions cluttering your namespace, than just create a package so that the helper function clutter the package namespace. If you don't like using helper functions at all, and just like having a single monolithic program, then I think you are headed down the wrong path. It is much easier to develop and unit test individual helper functions.

Comment: @CarlWoll I really like internal functions. They help organize code by putting code where it only needs to be seen. Having everything in flat name space is generally not a good idea IMHO.  Using a package will just move the problem from cluttering the global context to the package context. This helps a little, but it will _not_ change the overall design of the program in terms of having helper function inside a module where they are only needed. Ok, I understand this is how Mathematica works. Module in Mathematica  sematics are different from traditional programming languages I've used before.

Comment: @Nasser It doesn't have to be flat. You can have a hierarchy of packages. If you load a package inside a package, then it won't be available outside the package into which it was loaded. (See "private import" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8385424/395258).)

Comment: @C.E. Well, ok. But this is all too complicated and overkill for wanting to just have internal function. You can see how easily this is done in Maple for example. But thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[First answer was wrong - deleted.]

**New answer**

I rather like Carl Woll's advice, but the problem is an interesting exercise nonetheless.

Here's an approach that leverages the fact that *Mathematics* rewrites pattern parameters (adds a `$`) when code is injected.  Wrap all the definitions in `Hold` and add the list of symbols defined by the definitions:

```
Hold[code, symbols]
```

Then inject `code` into the definition of the top-level function, with `symbols` localized with `Module`.  Here's an example that has several definitions to show better how it works (and was a problem in my original answer):

```
ClearAll[foo];
Hold[
   boo[a_Integer] := Module[{b = 5}, b + a];
   boo[a_Real] := Module[{b = 5}, b - a];
   boo[a_] := boo2[a];
   boo2[a_] := Module[{b = 10}, a*b],
   {boo, boo2}
 ] /.
  Hold[code_, symbols_] :>
   (foo[a_] := Module[symbols,
      code;
      {boo[2 a], boo2[a]}]);
```

Tests:

```
foo[3]
(*  {11, 30}  *)

foo[3.]
(*  {-1., 30.}  *)

foo[x]
(*  {20 x, 10 x}  *)
```

Check the definition of `foo`:

```
? foo
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I should probably add that this is not the way to create new code, as the OP also remarked. It's an *ad hoc* fix to existing code. And it's not bulletproof because *Mathematica's* renaming by adding a `$` is not bulletproof: `With[{code = a$}, f[a_, a$_] := code;]; ? f`.

Comment: It could also be a moving target, should that mode of renaming change. Hard-wiring code based on internal variable rewriting specifics is dangerous.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau At least [they're documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html), and they have been that way [since at least V2 (1991)](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v2/contents/2.6.4.pdf). [Incompatible changes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56728/incompatible-changes-since-mathematica-version-7) have happened before...one hopes always for the better.

Comment: They are renamed, yes, but there is no guarantee as to the specifics of the renaming. Examples indicate a `$` will be appended. But as they say in investment counseling, past behavior is not necessarily indicative of the future.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I don't see how the code above depends on the specifics of renaming, except in what turns out to be an unintended clash (and the warning/description can be updated as needed, I suppose). I mentioned the `$` to point out what to look for in the example, for those who did not realize that happened. Now if in a future change patterns are not renamed at all, then that would be a problem and the usefulness of this approach would have expired. But as I intimated in the answer, I don't think the usefulness of this sort of code-fixing is going to be that broad anyway.

Comment: Maybe it does not, I'm not sure. Anything that relies on a single dollar sign being appended is at a bit of risk. Things that rely on the `Module` approach of adding dollar sign and a (unique) number are far less at risk.

Answer (score 2):

There is a pattern that is if not a direct answer to the question, then at least related to it:

```
foo = Module[{bar, baz},
   bar[a_] := Module[{b = 10}, b + a^1];
   baz[a_] := Module[{b = 20}, b + a^2];
   Function[{a}, bar[a] + baz[a]]
   ];

foo[4]
```

> `50`

By returning a pure function, you get the scoping of the inner functions that you want and you get to use whatever input variable names you want for your main function.