# How to replace all elements of a list by a rule "element" -> "element_"

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, pattern-matching, argument-patterns

I have a list:

```
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j}
```

The goal is to get:

```
{a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_, j_}
```

I can replace one particular element by using:

```
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j} /. a -> a_
```

But my attemps to expand this approach to all elements doesn't work. 
What can I do?

Comment: `{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j} _ /. Times -> Pattern`, which "accidentally" works since `Times` is `Orderless` and `Blank[]` happens to come after the variables.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sneaky... I like it!  Actually I think you should put that in your answer; it's really fun.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard OK, done. Thanks,

Comment: Related: [(121845)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121845/121)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
Pattern[#, Blank[]] & /@ {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j}
(* {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_, j_} *)
```

An inspection of the `FullForm` of `a_` reveals why this works:

```
a_ // FullForm
(* Pattern[a, Blank[]] *)
```

We can abbreviate slightly if we realize that the `InputForm` of `Blank[]` is `_`:

```
Pattern[#, _] & /@ {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j}
(* {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_, j_} *)
```

As an alternative approach, one might think to use pattern-matching replacement instead:

```
Replace[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j}, s_Symbol :> s_, {1}]
(*
  RuleDelayed::rhs: Pattern s_ appears on the right-hand side of rule s_Symbol:>s_.
  {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_, j_}
*)
```

... but *Mathematica* issues a warning because most of the time having a pattern on the right-hand side of a rule is a mistake.  In this particular case it is *not* an error, so we have to use `Quiet` to tell *Mathematica* that:

```
Quiet[Replace[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j}, s_Symbol :> s_, {1}], RuleDelayed::rhs]
(* {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_, j_} *)
```

Comment: One could also seize the opportunity to write the first one with the new `OperatorApplied[Pattern][_] /@ {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j}`.

Answer (score 17):

A few additional alternatives to inject patterns on the rhs:

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j};

Replace[list, a_ :> (x_ /. x -> a), 1]
```

> {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_, j_}

```
Replace[list, a_ :> (Pattern[#, _] &@a), 1]
```

> {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_, j_}

```
Activate @ Replace[list, a_ :> Inactive[Pattern][a, _], 1]
```

> {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_, j_}

```
Replace[list, a_ :> foo[a, _], 1] /. foo -> Pattern
```

> {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_, j_}

Answer (score 9):

convert it to string and then deal with it

```
ToExpression@StringJoin[#,"_"]&/@ToString/@{a,b,c,d,e}
```

a shorter way

```
ToExpression@StringJoin[ToString@#,"_"]&/@{a,b,c,d,e}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a (silly?) way

```
Insert[Pattern/@#,Blank[],{#,2}&/@Range@Length@#]&@{a,b}
```

> ```
> {a_,b_}
> ```

It works with held expressions

```
a=1;
b=2;
Insert[Pattern/@#,Blank[],{#,2}&/@Range@Length@#]&@Hold[a,b]
```

> ```
> Hold[a_,b_]
> ```

The following is the silliest I could make it

```
#/.a_-> ReplacePart[#0[[1,2,1]],1-> #]&/@{a,b,c}
```

> ```
> {a_,b_,c_}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative:

```
Function[x, x_, Listable][{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j}]
(*  {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_, j_}  *)
```

---

Playful alternatives:
These work "accidentally", since `Times` is `Orderless` and `Blank[]` happens to come after the variables.

```
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j} _ /. Times -> Pattern
Pattern @@@ ({a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j} _)
```

Comment: Very nice!  One I'll try to remember.

Answer (score 5):

Other options to avoid the warning message:

```
With[{a = #}, a_] & /@ {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j}

Pattern[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j}, _] // Thread
```

Or to suppress it:

```
Cases[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j}, a_ :> a_] // Quiet
```

Answer (score 4):

Yet another way to do it (triggering a warning along the way)

```
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j} /. u_Symbol /; Context[u] == "Global`" :> u_
```

I had not realised you could use `Context` in pattern matching.