# General rule to rewrite function and argument into a new symbol

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation, rule, regular-expressions

I am trying to convert Mathematica output into equations I can plug into C. I am presently trying to convert expressions of the form

```
Derivative[1,0,0][f][t,x,y]
```

where f is function with an arbitrary name (e.g. it may be called f, g, func, etc), into expressions of the form

```
f_Dt
```

where f is the symbol for the original function, e.g. I want the general rule to map Derivative[1,0,0][g][t,x,y] to g_Dt as well. Is there a way of doing this? For example, applying

```
expression/.{Derivative[1,0,0][f_][t,x,y]->f_Dt}
```

(where "expression" is arbitrary) doesn't work.

To expand the scope of this question, more generally I would like to transform

```
Derivative[1,0,0][f][t,x,y]
```

to not just f_Dt, but also expressions like

```
f$D
```

or

```
fD
```

(i.e. expressions that don't just include the underscore after f).

Comment: Well if it's `Derivative[1,0,0][f][t,x,y]` then `Derivative[1,0,0][f_][T,R,Y]` clearly won't match that. Maybe you wanted `Derivative[1,0,0][f_][a_, b_, c_]`? By the way, why are you trying to transform it into something that looks like `f_Dy`? If you look at the `FullForm[f_Dy]` you get `Pattern[f, Blank[Dy]]` which is a pattern matching object and thus something that can't be used as a function name or anything like that.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Unfortunatelyt the [T,R,Y] is a typo (which I've corrected). I want to transform to something like f_Dy as that is the general name for a function derivative I am using in my C code.

Comment: Can you give us a sample `expression` where this fails? I'm almost certain your pattern just isn't quite flexible enough for what you want. Like you expect one form of the pattern but it turns out you have a different one.

Comment: In version 10.1 `Derivative[1, 0, 0][foo][t, x, y] /. {Derivative[1, 0, 0][f_][t, x, y] :> f_Dt}` yields `foo_Dt` along with a warning message that in this case can be ignored.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard For some reason that approach isn't working for more complicated algebraic expressions that also include derivatives of other functions (e.g. the expression includes derivatives of a function f, h, etc) .I'm also concerned by the warning Mathematica raises.

Comment: (1) Can you provide one or more of these cases as an example?  (2) The particular warning is because usually one does not want a named `Pattern` on the right side of a Rule; it's a common mistake like using `=` in place of `==` within `Solve`.  However if that is actually what one wants it can be safely ignored; see [(210799)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/210799/121) for example.

Comment: Usually, when you want to convert Mathematica expressions into C, you want to turn it into a string.  I suggest something like `"f_Dt"` instead of plain `f_Dt` which is interpreted by Mathematica as a pattern named `f` with head `Dt`.

Comment: @QuantumDot The problem with that approach is then I will covert, e.g. expression like Derivative[1,0,0][g][t,x,y] to "f_Dt", instead of "g_Dt"