# Writing a function with variable arguments

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

I want to write a function which takes multiple arguments varying from 1 to n, where each argument is a triplet.

sublistProduct[{$a_1,b_1,c_1$},{$a_2,b_2,c_2$},...] = { $\Pi_{i=1}^{i=n}a_i ,\Pi_{i=1}^{i=n} b_i,\forall i \;\;max(c_i) $}

Any suggestions to write this function without multiple declaration and overloading.

For example sublistProduct[{1,2,3},{2,3,3},{3,4,5}] = {6,24,5}
There can be any number of inputs(triplets) to the functions

Comment: Related or possible duplicates: [(6588)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6588/121), [(15749)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15749/121),
[(26686)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26686/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard definitely related. BTW, how do you keep track of all your answers? :)

Comment: @rcollyer For a while I was keeping a list, not only of *my* posts but any that were frequent duplicates, but recently I've just been using search which I seem to be getting better with.  However since I remember my own wording or style better than I recall others I seem to find more of my own answers.  I encourage you to link any I miss as you are able.  By the way I just added two more links; I think at least one of these is a duplicate.  Please vote if you agree.

Comment: @rcollyer Oops, one of those links was not a duplicate; I remembered it wrong.  See, I don't keep track very well. ;-p

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was the first vote.

Comment: @rcollyer So I see.  By the way I did vote for your answer below; it is specifically useful.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks. I need to stay ahead of the whippersnappers who are trying to push me off the first page.

Comment: @rcollyer \*chuckle\*

Comment: [15749](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15749/farg1-arg2-argn-vs-farg1-arg2-argn) , is not related to this. Also [26686](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26686/a-function-that-accepts-a-pair-or-a-list-of-pairs) this shows how to operate inside the tuple. It is possible to take transpose and operate over the elements, but I am not giving a list as input. So I have to convert it to a list.

Comment: @drdebmath 15749 is somewhat related though not an answer to this.  However [this answer of mine](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26690/121) shows exactly the same `Transpose` method and `Repeated` pattern that the Accepted answer below does, therefore I believe this does already have an answer as marked.  The only possible difference that I can see is the "convert it to a list" part which is exactly what 15749 is about.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard the references sure did help. Thanks for your other answers.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is in defining the pattern correctly. I would use something like this:

```
Clear[f]
f[terms : {_, _, _} ..] := terms
```

which when used does this

```
f[{1,2,3}]
(* {1,2,3} *)
f[{1,2,3}, {2,3,4}]
(* Sequence[{1,2,3}, {2,3,4}] *)
```

So, to make effective use of that pattern, I would then put it into a list, e.g.

```
Clear[f]
f[terms : {_, _, _} ..] := {terms}
```

so that I can manipulate it at will. For instance,

```
Clear[f]
sublistProduct[terms : {_, _, _} ..] := 
  {Times@@#1, Times@@#2, Max@#3}& @@ Transpose[{terms}]
```

Comment: This just creates clubbed list of terms in the first and second position of the triplet. Like sublistProduct[{1,2,2},{2,3,4}] = {{1,2},{2,3},4}

Comment: TImes function doesn't work on lists. Is there a method to remove the brackets from a list, when passing it to a function?

Comment: It worked, Just had to add another function Times2[{a__}]:= Times[a].. Thanks for the answer. I would have accepted it, had you included this also.

Comment: Better yet, just replace `Times@` with `Times@@`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP yes, that's a mistake in my answer. Fixing now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BlankSequence` in function definition, e.g. to get a list of all the first elements:

```
f[triplets__] := {triplets}[[All, 1]]
```

so you can use it as

```
f[{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2}]
(* {a1, a2} *)
```

Note that this doesn't actually restrict you to using triplets as arguments for `f`, just that you have to give it one or more arguments.