# make trace of a matrix listable?

Tags: list-manipulation, attributes

I have a list of 2 by 2 matrices and I want the list of their traces. I have been using

```
Map[Tr,mylistofmatrices]
```

But I wonder if there is a way to make    `Tr`    Listable so I can just call

```
Tr[mylistofmatrices]
```

Comment: Related:  [(6588)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6588/121),
[(15749)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15749/121),
[(26686)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26686/121)  (in my interpretation of this question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't.  There are several reasons for that:

- `Tr` operates on tensors of arbitrary rank, not just matrices
- `Listable` functions will automatically thread to the deepest level of lists, so if you set `Tr` to be `Listable`, it'll individually wrap each deepest element of a nested list, e.g. `Tr[{{1,2},{3,4}}]` would transform to `{{Tr[1], Tr[2]}, {Tr[3], Tr[4]}}`.

Just use `Map`, which is unambiguous and takes just one extra character to type ... `Tr /@ list` vs `Tr @ list`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have version 10 or later you can use operators forms, i.e. `Map[Tr]` acts as a function:

```
mylistofmatrices = {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{q, r, s}, {t, u, v}}};

Map[Tr][mylistofmatrices]
```

> ```
> {a + d, q + u}
> ```

This is a subtle difference but it may be useful nevertheless.

If you always want the trace of a tensor with a specific array depth you can check for that.  If you want only a two-dimensional tensor (which is what you state in your question) you can use [`MatrixQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixQ.html); otherwise look at [`ArrayDepth`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayDepth.html) and [`TensorRank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorRank.html).  One implementation:

```
myTr[m_?MatrixQ] := Tr[m]
myTr[{m__?MatrixQ}] := Tr /@ {m}
```

Now:

```
myTr @ foo
myTr @ {1, 2, 3}
myTr @ {{a, b}, {c, d}}
myTr @ mylistofmatrices
```

> ```
> myTr[foo]
>
> myTr[{1, 2, 3}]
>
> a + d
>
> {a + d, q + u}
> ```

Comment: Re: `TensorRank[]`, how very odd. "Introduced in 2012 (9.0)", and yet it's been around since the first version, and at one point ["replaced by `ArrayDepth`"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html#209457160).

Comment: @Guess The poor developers are run every which direction.  Rube Goldberg would love the present state of affairs. :o)

Comment: I am slightly frightened whenever I get into a situation where it turns out that I know even slightly more than the supposed experts… :o

Comment: @Guess I wouldn't jump to that conclusion in this case; I imagine the developers are well aware that this was a v1 function but someone probably told them to *pretend* that it was a new function in v9 as that has better publicity than "oops, we deprecated that but now see value in reintroducing it and applying it to this shiny new tensor stuff we'd like you to upgrade for" ;-)

Comment: Good point; but then, I spent some amount of time bitching about why they renamed `TensorRank[]`, so reading that "new" bit gave mixed emotions. :) Oh well, glad that it's "back".