# How to remove parentheses in a function's input?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists as follows:

{1,2,3} and {4,5,6}

And I have a function f

```
f[{1,2,3},{4,5,6}]:={{4,5,6},{1,2,3}};
```

I want

```
f[f[{1,2,3},{4,5,6}]]
```

But since the output of

```
f[{1,2,3},{4,5,6}]
```

has an extra parentheses, I cannot simply do it.

How to fix the problem so I can calculate

```
f[f[{1,2,3},{4,5,6}]]
```

and further

```
Nest[f,{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}},n]
```

Comment: You might find these topics of interest: [(6588)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6588/121), [(8382)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8382/121), [(15749)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15749/121), [(26686)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26686/121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you could define `f` as

```
f[{l1_, l2_}] := {l2, l1}
```

Then,

```
f[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
(* {{4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}} *)

f[f[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}} *)
```