# How can I define a Listable function only apply to a vector?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, recursion

Consider the function `f` which should behave as

```
f[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}}]
```

> ```
> {f[{1, 2}], f[{3, 4}], f[{5, 6, 7}]}
> ```

The following code doesn't worked as expectation

```
fromDig[ls_?VectorQ] := 10^Range[Length@ls - 1, 0, -1].ls;
SetAttributes[fromDig, Listable];
fromDig@{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}
```

I figured out a way, using `Compile`,

```
Clear["Global`*"];
cfromDig = Compile[{{A, _Integer, 1}},
 10^Range[Length@A - 1, 0, -1].A, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
cfromDig[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}]
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand, but why not just: `fromDig2[ls_List] := 10^Range[Length@# - 1, 0, -1].# & /@ ls;
fromDig2@{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}`? (or `FromDigits /@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}`:) )

Comment: ...or `fromDig3[ls__] := 10^Range[Length@{ls} - 1, 0, -1].{ls};
fromDig3 @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate but I spent 15 minutes looking for it and couldn't find it, so I'm just going to answer for now.

Instead of using `Listable` you can manually map over non-vector lists:

```
f[v_?VectorQ] := oper[v]
f[ls_List] := f /@ ls;

f[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}}]
```

> ```
> {oper[{1, 2}], oper[{3, 4}], oper[{5, 6, 7}]}
> ```

---

#### Extension

In an attempt to make this answer more unique, consider the advanced behavior of `Listable` functions wherein non-list arguments are distributed:

```
SetAttributes[ff, Listable]
ff["x", {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}]
```

> ```
> {ff["x", 1, 4], ff["x", 2, 5], ff["x", 3, 6]}
> ```

We may wish to have this behavior extended, in a fashion at least, to our "vector atoms" as used above.  The simplest method I can think of is to use `Thread`, which has the same behavior as `Listable` though only at level one, and guard the vectors form recognition and threading.  Here an unoptimized first pass at implementation:

```
g[a___] /; MemberQ[{a}, x_List /; ! VectorQ[x]] :=
  Module[{h},
    g @@@ Replace[Thread@Replace[Hold[a], v_?VectorQ :> h[v], {1}], h@x_ :> x, {2}]
  ]
```

Now:

```
g[1, {2, 3}, {{{4}}, {5, 6}, 7}]
```

> ```
> {{g[1, {2, 3}, {4}]}, g[1, {2, 3}, {5, 6}], g[1, {2, 3}, 7]}
> ```

Note that the vector `{2, 3}` is distributed as `1` is, while the nested lists are threaded.  When `{4}` is encountered it is also treated as atomic, but its surrounding `List` is transferred to the output: `{g[1, {2, 3}, {4}]}`.

Comment: I have the search problem for long time, too :)) Do you think we should move http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/managing-stackexchange-favorites-via-documentation-center question to the main site...

Comment: @s.s.o It's migrated now.  I hope you get an answer at last.