# Listable on first level

Tags: functions, function-construction, performance-tuning, functional-style, attributes

I have some function which take `List` as input.

```
f[l_List]:=someActions[l]
```

I need apply this function to a list of lists. Now I use this approach

```
lst = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
f /@ lst
(*{someActions[{1, 2}], someActions[{3, 4}]}*)
```

But as we [know](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica) `Map` over list is slower than using function with attribute `Listable`.

When I set attribute `Listable` to my function I get not expected result:

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable]
f[lst]
(*{{f[1], f[2]}, {f[3], f[4]}}*)
```

How can I use attribute `Listable` with function which take a list of lists as input?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(33046)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33046).  Leonid explains the performance issues of `Listable` here: [(35150)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35150)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.  If correct behaviour is

```
f[{{1,2},{3,4}}] -> {f[{1,2}],f[{3,4}]}
```

then what is correct behaviour for

```
f[{1,2}]
```

???  Clearly the second expression has no idea that it came from a previous application of `f` unless you find some way to tell it.

`Map` is the simple and correct way of achieving what you want; I don't believe that it is generally slower than `Listable`.  If you really want to use `Listable` I suggest you change the `Head` of the inner list to something other than `List`, e.g. `h`:

```
SetAttibutes[f, Listable]
lst = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
lst = h @@@ lst ;
f[lst]
(* {f[h[1,2]], f[h[3,4]]} *)
```