# define a function with optional arguments

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, optional-arguments

I have defined a function as follows:

```
fDistance[pointA_, pointB_: {0, 0}, metric_: "taxi"] := 
 Module[{interval}, 
  If[metric == "taxi", 
   interval = 
    Abs[pointB[[1]] - pointA[[1]]] + Abs[pointB[[2]] - pointA[[2]]], 
   interval = 
    Sqrt[(pointB[[1]] - pointA[[1]])^2 + (pointB[[2]] - 
        pointA[[2]])^2]]; interval]
```

Then

```
fDistance[{3, 4}]
(*7; ok*)

fDistance[{3, 4}, {1, 2}, "euclid"]
(*2 Sqrt[2]; ok*)
```

But

```
fDistance[{3, 4}, "euclid"]
(*error message*)
```

How can I avoid that Mathematica assign the string literal 'euclid' to the variable pointB? It should have returned 5 as the output below shows

```
fDistance[{3, 4}, {0, 0}, "euclid"]
(*5*)
```

And as a second question:
Is it possible to call the function in the following manner

```
fDistance[pointB={1, 2}, metric='normal', pointA={3, 4}]
```

that is, its arguments are paired with a keyword instead of being in the correct order according to the function denition?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must add a restricting pattern to the second parameter.  Define your function like this:

```
fDistance[pointA_, pointB : {_, _} : {0, 0}, metric_: "taxi"] := (* rest of code *)

fDistance[{3, 4}, "euclid"]
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

Recommended reading:

- [How can I create a function with "positional" or "named" optional arguments?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1567/121)
- [How to Combine Pattern Constraints and Default Values for Function Arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4937/121)
- [Can I make a default for an optional argument the value of another argument?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15718/121)
- [A question about two ways to use Default](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45729/121)

---

For your second point you should first familiarize yourself with:

- [Guide: Options Management](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/OptionsManagement.html)
- [Tutorial: Manipulating Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingOptions.html)
- [Functions with Options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/353/121)

Then return to the first link in this post for how this will relate to default arguments.

As a brief example of setting up your function to use *only* named options:

```
ClearAll[fDistance]

Options[fDistance] =
  {"pointA" -> {0, 0}, "pointB" -> {0, 0}, "metric" -> "taxi"};

fDistance[OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{pointA, pointB, metric},
  {pointA, pointB, metric} = OptionValue[{"pointA", "pointB", "metric"}];
  If[metric == "taxi", 
    Abs[pointB[[1]] - pointA[[1]]] + Abs[pointB[[2]] - pointA[[2]]], 
    Sqrt[(pointB[[1]] - pointA[[1]])^2 + (pointB[[2]] - pointA[[2]])^2]
  ]
]

fDistance[]
fDistance["pointA" -> {3, 4}]
fDistance["metric" -> "euclid", "pointA" -> {3, 4}]
```

> ```
> 0
>
> 7
>
> 5
> ```

This may also be of use and/or interest to you:

- [Functions with changeable global variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134381/121)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. Regarding the second question is it possible something like the following:                               `fDistance[pointB={1, 2}, metric='normal', pointA={3, 4}]` ? If yes how I should modify the definition of the function?

Comment: @dimitris Sorry, I overlooked that in a hurry to answer.  Yes, those are known as Options in *Mathematica.* Let me gather some links.

Comment: No reason to apologize:-)! Take your time. Thanks also for the useful links. I think after almost 10 years I have to revisit http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/Tricks.html

Comment: @dimitris In case you have somehow missed it be sure also to read: http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/Book.html

Comment: Definitely the Holy Grail of Mathematica Programming-)!

Comment: @dimitris I quickly reviewed the links I gave and I didn't see a short example of a function with only named options and no formal parameters so I added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for the edited answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I really like "recommend reading" sections in answers. In that case we not only get the "How" ( as asked ) but also the "Why".