# How to pass a list as function argument?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, variable

I have the following function

```
lFreqPhylo[a_, Q_, b_, p_] :=  Sum[Log[freqFunction[r[[p]][[i]], L[[p]][[i]], a, Q, b, {i, 1, nbranches[[p]]}];
```

The objects *L*, *r* and *nbranches* are simply lists of data, and the argument p tells the function which dataset to refer to.

I'd like to define a function which sums all of the datasets (here n=2) and uses a different argument a and b for each dataset, so to write it our by hand,

```
lFreqPhylo[a1, Q, b1, 1] + lFreqPhylo[a2, Q, b2, 2]
```

To this end, I defined two lists,

```
A = {a1,a2}
```

and

```
B = {b1,b2}
```

(This list has more elements but I'm giving the example of 2 elements to keep it simple.) What this means is that I'd need to pass the lists A, B and the index to each list (p in lFreqPhylo) to a new function lFreq. The following approach however failed:

```
lFreq[A__, B__, Q_] := Sum[lFreqPhylo[A[[p]], Q, B[[p]], p], {p, 1, 2}]; (*Doesn't work!*)
```

How can I pass the two lists, A and B, to the function lFreqPhylo such that I can (a) use the 'Sum[...]' expression on the right hand side, (b) use the list elements, a1, a2, b1 and b2, as arguments of the function?

Thanks in advance,
Rafal

Comment: Kuba,

Well, problem is I have two lists and need to pass an index of the list as an argument. So following your advice, having defined two lists,

A = {a1,a2};
B = {b1,b2};

I did

    f1[a_, b_, Q_] := (a b)^2/Q;
    f2[Q_, a__, b__] := Total[MapThread[f1[#1, #2, Q] &, {A, B}]];

and now it works. But what if I have 

    f1[a_, b_, Q_,i_] := (a b)^2/Q i

where i is the index of the element of the list (1 or 2)? How do I define f2 then?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I've now edited it.

Comment: Change the LHS of your definition to `lFreq[A_, B_, Q_]` and it works as expected; no?

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**

The definition you make

```
lFreq[A__, B__, Q_] := [...]
```

is not very nice. There is an ambiguity here and Mathematica will not know how many elements to match to `A` and how many to match to `B`. We can check this by defining

```
lFreqTest[A__,B__]:= {A}
```

Then

```
lFreqTest[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

gives

> ```
> {1}
> ```

So that we see that Mathematica tries to make `B__` as long as possible. There is a terrible way around this

```
Clear@tester
tester[PatternSequence[a__, b__] /; (Length@{a} == Length@{b})] := "ok"
```

which gives

```
tester[1,2]
```

> ```
> "ok"
> ```

```
tester[1,2,3]
```

> ```
> tester[1,2,3]
> ```

But this will be very slow. You should look to alternatives.

**Original**

How about this?

```
A = {1, 2};
B = {2, 3};
Q = 6;
```

The actual functions

```
f1[a_, b_, Q_, i_] := (a b)^2/Q;

lFreq[listA_, listB_, Q_] :=

lFreq[listA_, listB_, Q_] :=
 Total@
  MapThread[
   f1[#1, #2, Q, #3] &
   ,
   {listA, listB, Range[Length@listA]}
   ]
```

Now we have

```
lFreq[A, B, Q]
```

> ```
> 20/3
> ```

Comment: Jacob, I have now changed the original question such that it contains all the sub-questions I had. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I've written the following and it seems to work. Do you think this is better or do you think it will be slow too and should I find another way?

lFreqPhylo[a_, Q_, b_, p_] :=  Sum[Log[freqFunction[r[[p]][[i]], L[[p]][[i]], a, Q, b]], {i, 1, nbranches[[p]]}];

lFreqPhylo2[listA_, listB_, Q_] := Total@MapThread[ lFreqPhylo[#1, Q, #2, #3] &, {listA, listB, Range[Length@listA]}];

lFreq[A_, B_, Q_] := Evaluate[lFreqPhylo2[A, B, Q]];

Comment: @Rafal that looks quite reasonable. Just so you know, you can write `r[[p]][[i]]` as `r[[p, i]]`. Furthermore your definition for lFreq may be a bit tricky. Either `Q` `A` and `B` are already set, and it is misleading to have them as function arguments. Or they are not set, and `MapThread` will probably fail. Maybe it works if you define this function before you define `lFreqPhylo2`, `A`, `B` and `Q`.

Comment: [`Longest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Longest.html) can help here.

Comment: +1 for `tester[PatternSequence[a__, b__] /; (Length@{a} == Length@{b})] := "ok"`

Answer (score 3):

What about the following approach:

```
lFreq[A_List, B_List, Q_]:=Sum[Function[i, lFreqPhylo[A[[i]], Q, B[[i]], i][j], {j, 1, 2}]
```

This produces the correct output for the given example of 2 elements:

```
lFreqPhylo[a1, Q, b1, 1] + lFreqPhylo[a2, Q, b2, 2]
```