# How can I define a function that takes a list of reals?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to define a function `f` which takes a list of reals. My purpose is to build a function which I can give a list of reals, integers or strings and have it build an appropriate probability distribution for.

So I'd like to do something like

```
f[{samples_Real}]:=makeRealDist[samples];
f[{samples_Integer}]:=makeInteger[samples];
f[{samples_String}]:=makeCategoricalDist[samples];
```

I can easily match on `Real`/`Integer`/`Strings`.
The part I can't figure out is how to match on a list of `Real`/`Integer`/`String`.

Comment: Almost there! `f[{samples__Real}]` or `f[samples:{__Real}]`

Comment: That seems about right for what I want, thank you! I was close. However, samples is then treated as a "Squence[samples]", I was expecting just a list of reals/integers/strings like {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}. I'm obviously missing something in my understanding, any pointers to what that might be? I'm hoping to pass this list on to my makeRealDist function...

Comment: The second option will give you a list.

Comment: You can also use `Repeated` (`..`), but here `BlankSequence` (`__`) is simpler.

Comment: f[samples:{__Real}] Seems to be exactly what I was looking for. But what is the difference between {Samples__Real} and samples:{_Real} ?

Comment: Are you sure you want Real?  This way `3` will be rejected, but `3.` will be accepted. Why not check for NumericQ? but may be you really want Real.

Comment: Basically everything on the LHS of `:=` is a pattern (not technically a `Pattern` but no matter), so it's just a question of what parts of that pattern you want to attach a definition to for use on the RHS. So `samples__Real` means you are capturing the sequence itself, whereas `samples:{__Real}` means you are capturing the list (which is just the head `List` wrapped around a sequence).

Comment: @Nasser's suggestion is a good one unless you have a specific need for `Real`s. You'd implement it like this: `f[samples:{__?NumericQ}]`

Comment: @Nasser I'm actually overloading the function for lists of different types. So I can take data of different types and have a single code path dealing with it:
f[samples:{__Real}]:=somethingReal[samples];
f[samples:{__Integer}]:=somethingUnreal[samples];
f[samples:{__String}]:=secondReality[samples]; Imagine pulling data out of a database, I can map each column full of data. Map[f, DBQueryResults]

Answer (score 6):

I feel that the basics of this topic are well covered in my answer to:

- [Can a function be made to accept a variable amount of inputs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6588/121)

Once you have read that and understand [`BlankSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankSequence.html), [`Repeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Repeated.html), and [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pattern.html) you will understand that you could use either of these:

```
f1[samples : {__Real}]   := makeRealDist[samples]
f2[samples : {_Real ..}] := makeRealDist[samples]
```

If you wish to permit integers, fractions, etc, you can use [`NumberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberQ.html) or perhaps even [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumericQ.html).
Viable semantics include:

```
f3[samples_List] /; VectorQ[samples, NumberQ] := makeRealDist[samples]
f4[samples : {__?NumberQ}] := makeRealDist[samples]
```

Timings will show that the first forms (`f1` and `f3`) are to be preferred:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

packed = Range[1, 1000, 0.0001];
timeAvg @ #[packed] & /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4}
```

> ```
> {3.67616*10^-7, 0.1404, 5.59104*10^-7, 1.201}
> ```

Comment: `Blacksequence`? That sure soundeth sinister, nay, eldritch even. Goes well with your username, too :D

Comment: @Yves You mean you don't mutter dark incantations as you code? :o)

Comment: Well, more like PEGI 18 obscenities, at times. But they most assuredly do not help with the code as such. Hmm, worth a try. Now where did I put my [Necronomicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necronomicon) again? Ah... right next to my NKS special edition and the [Laundry files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Stross#The_Laundry_Files) :D

Comment: f1[samples : {__Real}]   := makeRealDist[samples] Reads cleanest to me, and has a benefit of being quite fast. Thank you all who helped.

Comment: @user159805 You are welcome for my part.  If you find this answer fully satisfactory please consider [Accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) it.  Also please consider choosing a more "human" username.