# Quick way to use conditioned patterns when defining multi-argument function?

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, conditional, argument-patterns

I have a simple function that is supposed to only accept numeric values (i.e. complex/real numbers and constant symbols e.g. Pi, E).

$$f(a,b,c)=a+b+c$$

**Edit**: I should have chosen a less simple function for this question as there might be approaches that will work for this simple function but not for functions in general (1-see end of question). Please think of a more complicated function, such as $$f(a,b,c)=a^2 \sin(b) \log(c)$$ when you're thinking of an answer.

I know that one can use [_?NumericQ](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820) for each parameter such that only numeric values of that parameters are entered into the function (click [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PuttingConstraintsOnPatterns.html) for more information on putting constrains on patterns).

```
Clear[f1]
f1[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := a + b + c

f1 @@@ {{1, 2, 3}, {x, y, z}, {1, y, z}, {x, 2, z}, {x, y, 3}}
(* {6, f[x, y, z], f[1, y, z], f[x, 2, z], f[x, y, 3]} *)
```

However, for functions with more than 1 variables, I'm way too lazy to add NumericQ after each parameter. Using /; at the end of the function definition works, but I feel it's still too long and I have to retype the name of the parameters (a,b,c) at the end.

```
Clear[f2, f3]
f2[a_, b_, c_] := a + b + c /; And @@ (NumericQ[#] & /@ {a, b, c})
f3[a_, b_, c_] := a + b + c /; VectorQ[{a, b, c}, NumericQ]
```

Is there any way to express the condition only once, and without having to type the list of parameters one more time? I know that this is a frivolous question borne out of sheer laziness but I'd love to hear your ideas.

(1) such as using the [double underscore (BlankSequence)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankSequence.html) to apply NumericQ to any number of arguments passed to Plus (per Kuba's helpful suggestion). This is because these arguments have identical hierarchy in the function--thus having no need for parameters with different names to represent them--and because Plus can take any number of arguments.

```
Clear[f4]
f4[a__?NumericQ] := Plus[a]

f4 @@@ {{1, 2, 3}, {x, y, z}, {1, y, z}, {x, 2, z}, {x, y, 3}}    
(* {6,f4[x,y,z],f4[1,y,z],f4[x,2,z],f4[x,y,3]} *)
```

Comment: Thank you Kuba. This is a very neat way to apply conditionals to parameters for n-ary functions (eg. Plus) where the arguments have the same hierarchy, but I'm wondering if--and if so, how--to use this for more general functions. Again thank you for showing me this neat trick.

Comment: If you don't mind encasing arguments into a list, something like this would do for any generic function: `bob[args : {a_, b_, c_, d_}] := a*b+c/d /; VectorQ[args, NumericQ]`

Comment: @rasher Nice alternative.

Comment: Thanks rasher! Your comment, for now, is the closest to what my inner sloth envisions.

Comment: It seems this works `test[PatternSequence[a_, b_, c_]?NumericQ] := {a, b, c}` but I'm not exactly sure why :)

Comment: @Kuba Why wouldn't it work?  seismatica, please see my updated answer for my proposal for this kind of variation.

Comment: I'm studying your post @Mr.Wizard since it's so wonderfully involved. I'm going to bed and might have to read it in more details tomorrow. Thank you again for your effort!

Comment: @Kuba `PatternTest` applies individually to elements of a sequence and `PatternSequence` is ostensibly a sequence.  seismatica, you're welcome.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, it is what I was missing. I should read details&options more often :P

Comment: Did you delete your first comment (using __) @Kuba? I learned a great deal from that comment so could you perhaps repost it? If you're not inclined to do so I'm more than happy to post what I remembered from that comment.

Comment: @seismatica you can add it to your question with explanation that it is not the case because you have to work with named arguments :) I've deleted it since it was off topic, sorry

Comment: @seismatica,What IDE do you use as the picture show?

Comment: Related, simpler question: [(51382)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51382)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### Ramblings

Arguments of the left-hand-side head are evaluated in the course of function definition, therefore you can use a utility function that constructs the patterns that you want.  For example:

```
SetAttributes[nq, HoldFirst]
Quiet[
 nq[s_Symbol] := s_?NumericQ
]
```

Now:

```
ClearAll[f]

f[nq @ a, nq @ b, nq @ c] := a + b + c

Definition[f]
```

> ```
> f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := a + b + c
> ```

Doing this you lose the nice syntax highlighting shown in the original.

If you `Block` all Symbols you could even `Map` the utility function, e.g.:

```
Block[{f, a, b, c},
  Evaluate[nq /@ f[a, b, c]] := a + b + c
]
```

This hardly feels like a clean solution however.  Perhaps you merely want something shorter than verbatim `NumericQ`?  At risk of a tautology you could always do something like:

```
ClearAll[f]

q = NumericQ;
f[a_?q, b_?q, c_?q] := a + b + c
```

But this requires you to keep the Global definition `q` or it will break as it is not expanded to `NumericQ` in the definition itself:

```
Definition[f]
```

> ```
> f[a_?q, b_?q, c_?q] := a + b + c
> ```

#### Metaprogramming approach

Another approach would be to write a function to modify all `Pattern` objects on the left-hand-side at the time of assignment.  Something like:

```
SetAttributes[defWithTest, HoldFirst]

defWithTest[(s : Set | SetDelayed)[LHS_, RHS_], test_] := 
  s @@ Join[Hold[LHS] /. p_Pattern :> p?test, Hold[RHS]]
```

Now:

```
ClearAll[f]

defWithTest[
  f[a_, b_, c_] := a + b + c,
  NumericQ
]

Definition[f]
```

> ```
> f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := a + b + c
> ```

---

### Proposed solution

As Kuba and rasher show in the comments you could also use clever alternatives to the explicit form `f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ]`.  Inspired by those comments I propose:

```
SetAttributes[numArgsQ, HoldFirst]
numArgsQ[_[___?NumericQ]] := True
```

Now:

```
ClearAll[f]

f[a_, b_, c_]?numArgsQ := a + b + c
```

Test:

```
f[1, 2, 3]
f["a", 2, 3]
```

> ```
> 6
>
> f["a", 2, 3]
> ```

For examples of advanced argument testing with an emphasis on messages please see:

- [How to check the style and number of arguments like the built-in functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85821/how-to-check-the-style-and-number-of-arguments-like-the-built-in-functions/86604#86604)

Note how (some) internal functions pass additional argument checking (and message generation) to an auxiliary function, e.g. `ChartArgCheck`, much as I did in the minimal application of `numArgsQ` above.

Comment: Leave it you you to make it elegant... +1 as always.

Comment: @rasher Thank you. :-)

Comment: Very nice. Fun fact: One of the first hit googling for "wizard rambling" is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEMXYJeCNPY

Comment: @Yves Interesting, though I didn't understand a lot of it.

Comment: The lyrics are below the video ;-) Will remove if you deem it too whimsical.

Comment: I think I know how your proposed solution works, but I just want to make sure I'm getting it correctly since I'm new to pattern-testing (and patterns in general): numArgsQ will return true for any function whose arguments are numerics?

Comment: @seismatica Yes, that's correct, but more specifically it will return `True` for any expression whose arguments are numeric.  For example all four cases are `True`: `numArgsQ /@ {Subscript[Pi, 3.14], E -> I, 3 + 4 I, 3/7}`. See the `FullForm` of the expressions for better understanding.  If any remain enigmatic let me know and I'll explain.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

I was reading the comments to the question, and found that @Kuba had already provided the following answer. I think it's the cleanest solution, so it deserves to be an answer, but please credit him with the idea.

Another idea is to use [`PatternSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternSequence):

```
ClearAll[f]

f[PatternSequence[a_,b_,c_]?NumericQ] := a+b+c
```

Examples:

```
f[1,2,3]
f["a",2,3]
```

> 6
>
> f["a", 2, 3]

**Generalization**

We can generalize the idea behind this answer as follows:

```
SequencedPattern[a_] := PatternSequence[##]?a&
```

Then, we can use `SequencedPattern` as follows:

```
f[SequencedPattern[NumericQ][a_, b_, c_]] := a + b + c
```

The previous examples still work:

```
f[1, 2, 3]
f["a", 2, 3]
```

> 6
>
> f["a", 2, 3]

Here is another example using `SequencedPattern`:

```
f[SequencedPattern[PrimeQ][a_, b_, c_], d_] := (a+b+c)/d

f[2,3,4,10]
f[2,3,7,11]
```

> f[2, 3, 4, 10]
>
> 12/11

Comment: fantastic flocking share!!! this is one of those elusive holy grail functions (short, sweet, elegant, easy to implement) everyone has been looking for. It really needs to be worked into the language or at least added as a ResourceFunction`

Answer (score 3):

I think there is another way to do that:

```
f[s : (PatternSequence[_?NumericQ] ..)] /; Length[{s}] == 3 :=
 Function[{a, b, c}, a^2 Sin[b] Log[c]][s]
```

It's suitable for the cases that conditions are the same.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard What about my code?

Comment: FYI: @ notifications don't work unless a user has already commented.  This works too (+1), and you don't even need `PatternSequence`: `f[s__?NumericQ] /; Length[{s}] == 3` will work.  Personally I would rather avoid introducing a second construct (`Function`) for the purpose but that's really a matter of opinion.  There are many ways to accomplish this goal; in my answer I sought what I considered the cleanest approach.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You code s__?NumericQ ,which I have never noticed is new to me

Answer (score 0):

## A Slightly More Complex Case Where Level-1 Heads Can Vary

### 1. My way by defining a short alias for a long pattern because I don't know any better. However this works!

However before we start how can I add the following condition: `/;x!=y` preferably to `cpat` or inside the definition `zinfy1[(x:cpat,y:cpat)/;x!=y]` (does this look correct?) and not in the inside or at the end of the function body?

```
(* cpat for common pattern *)
(* all arguments Integers >= 0 or +Infinity *)
cpat = _Integer?(# >= 0 &) | Infinity;

zinfy1[x : cpat, y : cpat] := Style[#, 20, Bold, Green] & /@ {x, y};
zinfy1[x_, y_] := Style[#, 20, Bold, Red] & /@ {x, y};

(* should pass - all args Greeen *)
{zinfy1[1, 2], zinfy1[3, 2 + 3], zinfy1[Infinity, 1], zinfy1[0, 0]}

(* should fail- all args Red *)
{zinfy1[Infinity, -9], zinfy1[3, 2 - 3], zinfy1[-1 Infinity, 0], 
 zinfy1[-1, 1]}
```

### 2.  An Attempt to Implement `SequencePattern` on same function and test cases completely fails.

And I don't know why. Anyone here feeling a little adventurous up for the challenge?  I could sure use a little help solving this.

```
SequencedPattern[a_] := PatternSequence[##]?a &;
zinfy2[SequencedPattern[cpat][x_, y_]] := 
  Style[#, 20, Bold, Green] & /@ {x, y};
zinfy2[x_, y_] := Style[#, 20, Bold, Red] & /@ {x, y};

(* should pass - all args Greeen *)
{zinfy2[1, 2], zinfy2[3, 2 + 3], zinfy2[Infinity, 1], zinfy2[0, 0]}

(* should fail- all args Red *)
{zinfy2[Infinity, -9], zinfy2[3, 2 - 3], zinfy2[-1 Infinity, 0], 
 zinfy2[-1, 1]}
```