# Function as a sum over a list of functions

Tags: summation

I would like to evaluate the following function

```
q[beta_, gamma_] := Sum[R[[n, 3]]], {n, 3}];
q[Pi/3, Pi/4]
```

Over the matrix

```
R= {{Cos[beta] Cos[gamma], -Sin[gamma], 
    Sin[beta] Cos[gamma]}, {Cos[beta] Sin[gamma], Cos[gamma], 
    Sin[beta] Sin[gamma]}, {-Sin[beta], 0, Cos[gamma]}};
```

This above method, however, does not give any results. I then tried it (besed on [Define Function with Sum over a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72813/define-function-with-sum-over-a-list)):

```
q[beta_, gamma_, R_] := Sum[R[[n, 3]], {n, 1, Length@R}];
q[Pi/3, Pi/4, {R}]
```

that also did not work. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why this isn't working**

I believe your problem is that `beta` and `gamma` don't appear on the right hand side (rhs) explicitly in your definition of `q`, but only through `R`. This is a problem here because you're using `:=`, which does not evaluate its rhs until the function being defined is called.

After defining `q` as you have, evaluate `?q`—this will give you the definitions for `q`, and you'll see that `R` appears as a symbol there, not as something involving `beta` and `gamma`. So, `q[Pi/3, Pi/4]` gets replaced with `Sum[R[[n, 3]], {n, 3}]`, and `Pi/3` and `Pi/4` are thrown away. Then `R` is expanded into its definition.

**How to fix it**

There are a couple ways to fix this.

1. Make `R` a function: `R[beta_, gamma_] := <insert matrix here>`. Then use `q[beta_, gamma_] := Sum[R[beta, gamma][[n, 3]], {n, 3}]`.
2. Use `=` instead of `:=`. Unlike `:=`, `=` evaluates its rhs first. This is generally riskier and not recommended, since the arguments are not bound; if you have external definitions for the arguments, they'll be substituted in *before* the definition is created! So for example, `x = 3; f[x_] = x + 1` will make `f` *always* return `4`. This is not the case for `f[x_] = x + 1` when `x` has no prior definition, even if `x` is defined later, e.g. `f[x_] = x + 1; x = 3` produces an `f` that works as expected. So good variable hygiene is important.
3. Or, like, 2 but safer, inline the whole of `R`.

Comment: Your first suggestion works. Thanks!

Comment: Or `q[b_, g_] := Sum[R[[n, 3]], {n, 3}] /. {beta :> b, gamma :> g}`