# What is wrong with my code so it neither produces a correct plot nor an error message?

Tags: plotting, functions, warning-messages, parametric-functions, code-review

I am trying to define some initial functions and then using them to define my secondary functions and then plot the secondary functions. I am supposed to get two curves with a finite width representing the uncertainty in the model parameter sets $\{a1, b1, c1\}$ and $\{a2, b2, c2\}$ corresponding to functions $CDDHybrid$ and $CDD40$ respectively while the other two functions $CDDNoterdaeme$ and $CDDZwaan$ have no uncertainties in their parameters. Below is my code:

```
CDDHybrid[s_, a1_, b1_, c1_] := 10^(a1 + b1*c1 - b1*s)*Exp[-10^(s - c1)];
CDDHybridmean[s_] := 10^(-4.9684 - 0.88*s)*Exp[-10^(s - 20.82)];
CDD40[s_, a2_, b2_, c2_] := 10^(a2 + b2*c2 - b2*s)*Exp[-10^(s - c2)];
CDD40mean[s_] := 10^(-11.0765 - 0.57*s)*Exp[-10^(s - 20.55)];
CDDNoterdaeme[s_] := 10^(4.2502 - 1.27*s)*Exp[-10^(s - 21.26)];
CDDZwaan[s_] := 10^(3.378 - 1.24*s)*Exp[-10^(s - 21.2)];

LHSHybridmean[s_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Log[10]*10^u*CDDHybridmean[u], {u, s, Infinity}] ;
LHSHybrid[s_, a1_, b1_, c1_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Log[10]*10^u*CDDHybrid[u, a1, b1, c1], {u, s, Infinity}] ;
LHS40mean[s_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[10^u*Log[10]*CDD40mean[u], {u, s, Infinity}] ;
LHS40[s_, a2_, b2_, c2_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[10^u*Log[10]*CDD40[u, a2, b2, c2], {u, s, Infinity}] ;
LHSNoterdaeme[s_?NumericQ] :=  NIntegrate[10^u*Log[10]*CDDNoterdaeme[u], {u, s, Infinity}] ;
LHSZwaan[s_?NumericQ] :=  NIntegrate[10^u*Log[10]*CDDZwaan[u], {u, s, Infinity}] ;

With[{a1 = Interval[-23.29 + .04 {-1, 1}], 
  b1 = Interval[0.88 + .04 {-1, 1}], 
  c1 = Interval[20.82 + .01 {-1, 1}], 
  a2 = Interval[-22.79 + .06 {-1, 1}], 
  b2 = Interval[0.57 + .07 {-1, 1}], 
  c2 = Interval[20.55 + .03 {-1, 1}]}, 
 LogPlot[{Min[LHSHybrid[s, a1, b1, c1]], LHSHybridmean[s], 
   Max[LHSHybrid[s, a1, b1, c1]], Min[LHS40[s, a2, b2, c2]], 
   LHS40mean[s], Max[LHS40[s, a2, b2, c2]], LHSNoterdaeme[s], 
   LHSZwaan[s]}, {s, 20.3, 23.1}, PlotRange -> {10^-35., 1.0}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {3}, 4 -> {6}}, 
  FillingStyle -> {{Blue, Opacity[0.4]}, {Red, Opacity[0.4]}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Blue, Blue, Red, Red, Red, Brown, Green, Thick},
   Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["X[unit]", FontSize -> 26], Style["Y[unit]", FontSize -> 26]}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 26], 
  PlotLegend -> {Style["", 20], Style["Hybrid (2015)", 20], 
    Style["", 20], Style["", 20], Style["40 arcseconds(2015)", 20], 
    Style["", 20], Style["Noterdaeme (2009)", 20], 
    Style["Zwaan (2005)", 20]}]]
```

However, I am surprised that I am getting nothing out of it! Could any one see what is my mistakes?

Comment: `Min[LHSHybrid[s, a1, b1, c1]]` will not output anything meaningful because in the definition of `LHSHybrid`, `c1` has to satisfy `NumericQ`. `Interval` gives `False` when you apply `NumericQ`. The same applies with all other functions in `LogPlot` that have `a1`, `b1`, etc. in them.

In addition, `infinity` should have a capital i as the first letter, or else it will be treated as a variable. `Infinity` means infinity, and `infinity` means a variable named "infinity".

Comment: Thus, all of the functions in your `LogPlot` are not numeric, meaning nothing will be on the graph.

Comment: In fact, I meant "Infinity" somehow in pasting the copied lines, I wrote it as "infinity." I removed $?NumericQ$ from the definition of the functions which have constant parameters. It still doesn't work. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Even making all initial functions numeric in nature doesn't solve the problem. But I was able to plot another set of functions in which there were no integrations. So, what causes the problem is the introduction of integrations into my functions which I don't know how to handle.

Comment: So the only workaround seems to be removeing $?NumericQ$ AND replacing $NIntegrate$ with $Integrate$. But that is taking forever to run not mentioning intermediate warnings. Again, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: The four functions that only have `s` as input seems to work fine; try restarting the kernel. `NumericQ` is still a problem. Also, the problem with the functions involving `Interval`s is that `NIntegrate` cannot have `Interval`s in them.

Comment: Are you expecting to get an `Interval` from `NIntegrate`? If so, there might be a workaround to this.

Comment: Hi. I removed ?NumericQ all together and turned NIntegrate into Integrate. The code still runs hopelessly. Sure, I am expecting to get an interval from NIntegrate.

Comment: Hm, using `MinMax` does not work as intended...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40150/discussion-between-jhm-and-benjamin).

Comment: I think you can make your own interval function to plot the results, see the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Introduction

The first thing that I noticed is that the functional form for all of your `CDD` and `LHS` functions are identical.

I propose that rather than defining six functions for each, we define one function and change the input arguments to cover the various cases.

```
cdd[s_, a_, b_, c_] := 10^(a + b*c - b*s)*Exp[-10^(s - c)]

lhs[s_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Log[10]*10^u*cdd[u, a, b, c], {u, s, Infinity}]
```

Note that we use `NumericQ` for all of the input arguments to `lhs`. This will be required the results are plotted.

As an example, here is the output for the average parameters you had set for the first case

```
With[
 {
  a1 = -23.29,
  b1 = 0.88,
  c1 = 20.82,
  s = 20.3
  },
 {cdd[s, a1, b1, c1], lhs[s, a1, b1, c1]}
 ]
(* {1.08754*10^-23, 0.00291862} *)
```

### Interval

The problem you were experiencing is that you wanted to use `Interval` but it was not accepted by `NIntegrate` so one was stuck.

The strategy will be to create all permutations of the average inputs parameters +/- their deltas and compute the minimum and maximum.

So for the first step, imagine that we have three parameters `a`, `b` and `c` and when their respective delta is subtracted we have the minus version, `am`, `bm` and `cm`.

We can get a list of all permutation of minus

```
Flatten[Outer[List, {a, am}, {b, bm}, {c, cm}], 2]
(* {{a, b, c}, {a, b, cm}, {a, bm, c}, {a, bm, cm}, {am, b, 
  c}, {am, b, cm}, {am, bm, c}, {am, bm, cm}} *)
```

Clearly we can perform the same operation for adding the delta.

Next we will define two functions that use `lhs` but compute the minimum of subtracting the delta values and the maximum of adding the delta values.

The case is covered where delta is zero for a particular parameter.

```
lhsMinus[s_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, da_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, 
  db_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, dc_?NumericQ] := Module[
  {
   aList,
   bList,
   cList
   },
  aList = If[da == 0, {a}, {a, a - da}];
  bList = If[db == 0, {b}, {b, b - db}];
  cList = If[dc == 0, {c}, {c, c - dc}];

  Min[Map[lhs[s, Sequence @@ #] &, 
    Flatten[Outer[List, aList, bList, cList], 2]]]
  ]

lhsPlus[s_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, da_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, 
  db_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, dc_?NumericQ] := Module[
  {
   aList,
   bList,
   cList
   },
  aList = If[da == 0, {a}, {a, a + da}];
  bList = If[db == 0, {b}, {b, b + db}];
  cList = If[dc == 0, {c}, {c, c + dc}];

  Max[Map[lhs[s, Sequence @@ #] &, 
    Flatten[Outer[List, aList, bList, cList], 2]]]
  ]
```

### Plot

Now plot the results for the first set of parameters. For the large spread in the `s` values the delta's had to be increased or the min and max were too close to be visible.

```
With[
 {
  a1 = -23.29,
  da = 0.08,
  b1 = 0.88,
  db = 0.08,
  c1 = 20.82,
  dc = 0.04
  },
 LogPlot[
  {
   lhsMinus[s, a1, da, b1, db, c1, dc],
   lhs[s, a1, b1, c1],
   lhsPlus[s, a1, da, b1, db, c1, dc]
   },
  {s, 20.3, 23.1},
  {PlotStyle -> {Blue, Black, Red}},
   PlotRange -> {10^-35, 1}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I think this should get you started. I leave to you the plot of the second data set.

### Numerical Derivatives and a faster version

If one were able to ascertain the polarity that a change in a parameter has on the outcome one could construct a faster version by reducing the number of permutations.

```
testDeriv = With[
  {
   a1 = -23.29,
   b1 = 0.88,
   c1 = 20.82
   },
  Table[
   {s, (lhs[s, a1 + 0.001, b1, c1] - lhs[s, a1, b1, c1])/0.001,
    (lhs[s, a1, b1 + 0.001, c1] - lhs[s, a1, b1, c1])/0.001,
    (lhs[s, a1, b1, c1 + 0.001] - lhs[s, a1, b1, c1])/0.001},
   {s, 20.3, 23.3, 0.5}
   ]
  ]

(* {{20.3, 0.00672811, 0.00102687, 0.0117371}, {20.8, 
  0.00194452, -0.000360691, 0.00494013}, {21.3, 
  0.000116524, -0.0000671435, 0.000553761}, {21.8, 
  7.0401*10^-8, -7.15508*10^-8, 8.08399*10^-7}, {22.3, 
  2.90222*10^-17, -4.32226*10^-17, 9.63237*10^-16}, {22.8, 
  4.69431*10^-46, -9.28372*10^-46, 5.11146*10^-44}, {23.3, 
  3.58277*10^-136, -8.85485*10^-136, 1.5721*10^-133}} *)
```

It appears that the derivative of `lhs` with respect to `a` and `c` is always positive and with respect to `b` may be either positive or negative.

Using that hypothesis a faster version of the `lhs` for intervals would be:

```
lhsMinus2[s_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, da_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, 
  db_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, dc_?NumericQ] := Module[
  {
   aList,
   bList,
   cList
   },
  aList = If[da == 0, {a}, {a - da}];
  bList = If[db == 0, {b}, {b, b - db, b + db}];
  cList = If[dc == 0, {c}, {c - dc}];

  Min[Map[lhs[s, Sequence @@ #] &, 
    Flatten[Outer[List, aList, bList, cList], 2]]]
  ]
```

and indeed testing shows that it does produce a smaller minimum:

```
testMinus = With[
   {
    a1 = -23.29,
    da = 0.04,
    b1 = 0.88,
    db = 0.04,
    c1 = 20.82,
    dc = 0.01
    },
   Table[
    {s, lhsMinus[s, a1, da, b1, db, c1, dc], 
     lhsMinus2[s, a1, da, b1, db, c1, dc]},
    {s, 20.3, 23.3, 0.5}
    ]
   ];

Map[{#[[1]], #[[3]]/#[[2]]} &, testMinus]
(* {{20.3, 1.}, {20.8, 0.98248}, {21.3, 0.947516}, {21.8, 
  0.909672}, {22.3, 0.870701}, {22.8, 0.832196}, {23.3, 0.794958}} *)
```

The same is true for the positive side:

```
lhsPlus2[s_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, da_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, 
  db_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, dc_?NumericQ] := Module[
  {
   aList,
   bList,
   cList
   },
  aList = If[da == 0, {a}, {a + da}];
  bList = If[db == 0, {b}, {b, b - db, b + db}];
  cList = If[dc == 0, {c}, {c + dc}];

  Max[Map[lhs[s, Sequence @@ #] &, 
    Flatten[Outer[List, aList, bList, cList], 2]]]
  ]

testPlus = With[
  {
   a1 = -23.29,
   da = 0.04,
   b1 = 0.88,
   db = 0.04,
   c1 = 20.82,
   dc = 0.01
   },
  Table[
   {s, lhsPlus[s, a1, da, b1, db, c1, dc], 
    lhsPlus2[s, a1, da, b1, db, c1, dc]},
   {s, 20.3, 23.3, 0.5}
   ]
  ];

Map[{#[[1]], #[[3]]/#[[2]]} &, testPlus]
(* {{20.3, 1.}, {20.8, 1.01669}, {21.3, 1.05383}, {21.8, 
  1.09744}, {22.3, 1.14645}, {22.8, 1.19945}, {23.3, 1.25562}} *)
```

Comment: @Benjamin For a shorter alternative to repeated use of `?NumericQ` please see [(52057)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52057/121)