# Apply same type checking to every argument

Tags: function-construction, argument-patterns

Consider the following function which takes 10 arguments.

```
f[Io_, {θ_, ϕ_}][{x0_, y0_, z0_}, d_][h_][L_][ω_]
```

I know that all of these are of same type. I would like to apply type checking, say [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html), to every argument. Currently, I do it like this by explicitly typing [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html)after every argument.

```
f[Io_?NumericQ, {θ_?NumericQ, ϕ_?NumericQ}][{x0_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ, z0_?NumericQ}, d_?NumericQ]
[h_?NumericQ][L_?NumericQ][ω_?NumericQ]
```

Is there a simpler way to apply type checking for every argument?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/52058

Comment: Thank you @AlexeyGolyshev. This is exactly what I need. I think this question can be tagged as a duplicate.