# return {} when the function is given {}

Tags: functions, function-construction, parametric-functions

I have a function taking an array as argument and giving an output. However, sometimes my argument is {} (the empty array), then how can I get an output {} when my argument is {}? Actually, I want the output to be {} if there is anything wrong with the argument. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you post your code, please? Or otherwise describe what you mean by something being wrong with the argument? Thanks.

Comment: `f[x_List] := If[Length[x] == 0, {}, func]`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Actually, I want the output to be {} if there is anything wrong with the argument.

For this I recommend one or more definitions with patterns that only match a valid argument, and a fall-through definition for anything else.  For example if the argument should be a nonempty list of integers:

```
(* primary definition *)
func[arg : {__Integer}] := Mean[arg]

(* fall-through definition *)
_func := {}
```

test:

```
func[{1, 2, 3}]
func[{1.23}]
func[{}]
func[1, 2, 3]
```

> ```
> 2
>
> {}
>
> {}
>
> {}
> ```

Additional reading:

- [How to check the style and number of arguments like the built-in functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85821/121)
- [Quick way to use conditioned patterns when defining multi-argument function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52057/121)

Comment: It is the fist time I see `_func := ...`, don't act like it isn't awesome!

Comment: @Kuba Thank you, but I suspect you've seen it before and have forgotten.  Likewise I seem to have forgotten who I learned it from.  Nevertheless it's good I guess that this answer can remind people of this useful pattern construct. :-)

Answer (score 4):

One way is to make some definitions

```
foo[arr_] := {}
foo[{}] := {} 
foo[arr_List] := "ok"
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica will automatically pick the correct definition to use.

Comment: I define my function as foo[points : {{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ..}]. It is an array like this {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},...}. Then when I define foo[arr_]:={}, my function foo produces null only.

Comment: Why not just define `foo[{}]={}`?

Comment: @JohnDoty yes, thanks, that is shorter. I guess I was trying to be explicit. But will update to use the shorter syntax.

Comment: @lol Please update answer with MWE then. btw, you need to add '_' after the symbol name. So instead of `foo[arr]:={}` it should be `foo[arr_]:={}` may be that is why it did not work for you.