# How to remove a line of a matrix if not all elements are numeric?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, filtering

I have a matrix a `n` columns and `m` lines. I'd like to efficiently remove the lines that are not entirely composed of numeric values, lines like this:

```
{6.22926,6.23254,6.23128,,6.23453,6.22548,6.22938,6.23443,}
```

In this case the last element is not a numeric value, and such line should be removed.

Also, the matrix is quite big, I have no clue what an efficient method would be.

Comment: Thanks for the various answers, I'm not yet confortable with these syntax.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following should work:

> ```
> lis = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 9, , 4, 6, 2}, {4, a, 3, 7, 1, 2}, 
>       {3.4, 5.2, 6.5, 7.7, 6.1, 2}};
> ```

Then:

```
Cases[lis, {__?NumericQ}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {3.4, 5.2, 6.5, 7.7, 6.1, 2}}
> ```

We can also use `VectorQ` with `Select`

```
Select[lis, VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &]
```

If you have **Version 10**, the following works:

```
Select[lis, AllTrue @ NumericQ]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
m = {{6.22926, 6.23254, 6.23128, 0, 6.23453, 6.22548, 6.22938, 
   6.23443, 0}, {6.22926, 6.23254, 6.23128, , 6.23453, 6.22548, 
   6.22938, 6.23443,}}

Select[m, MatrixQ[{#}, NumericQ] &]
```

> ```
> {{6.22926, 6.23254, 6.23128, 0, 6.23453, 6.22548, 6.22938, 6.23443, 0}}
> ```

more alternatives for speed comparisons.

Answer (score 6):

```
m = {{1, 2, 3}, {, 2, 3}, {1.1, 2, 3}, {1.1, , 3}}

DeleteCases[m, 
 Alternatives @@ Select[m, MemberQ[#, _?(Not[NumericQ[#]] &)] &]]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1.1, 2, 3}}

**Edit**

A timing comparison.  First creating a matrix:-

```
m = RandomReal[1, {10000, 10000}];

(* Adding some blanks *)
(m[[Sequence @@ #]] = "") & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 10000}, {2000, 2}];
```

Comparing the various solutions:-

```
First@Timing[a = Cases[m, {__?NumericQ}]]
```

> 19.141323

```
First@Timing[b = Select[m, MatrixQ[{#}, NumericQ] &]]
```

> 0.468003

```
First@Timing[
  c = DeleteCases[m, 
    Alternatives @@ Select[m, MemberQ[#, _?(Not[NumericQ[#]] &)] &]]]
```

> 85.862950

```
a == b == c
```

> True

Comment: Nice comparison, but why not `VectorQ`, e.g. [(51385)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51385)?