# The Apply function is only operating on my first list element - how to get it to work on the entire list

Tags: function-construction

I'm trying to understand the Map and Apply notation and ran into a problem.

I define this function:

```
f23 = Function[x, x^2];
Map[f23, {1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 8}]
```

and correctly get

```
{1, 4, 16, 36, 25, 64}
```

or

```
f23[{1, 4, 16, 36, 25, 64}]
```

yields

```
{1, 4, 16, 36, 25, 64}
```

but if I use Apply

```
Apply[f23, {12, 2, 4, 6, 5, 8}]
```

I only get

```
144
```

the first element. If I try using @@ it behaves just as Apply as expected.

So if I understand why apply is only operating on the first element, I can perhaps continue to learn how to use @@

Update:
    f23@{12, 2, 4, 6, 5, 8}

gets me

```
{144, 4, 16, 36, 25, 64}
```

So it appears I don't understand the apply @@ function

Comment: It is not `Apply`, your function is defined to care about the first argument only. Confusing part is that `x^2` threads over lists that is why `f23[{..}]` returns a list. You can `Trace` to check.

Comment: Aside a simple mistake with argument you can find answers in: [Scan vs. Map vs. Apply](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46238/5478). Is it enough?

Comment: @Kuba, I've got to read up on what a "head" is. Might make sense then, but thanks for the link

Comment: @kuba  - can you give me an example of how I'd make the function care about more than just the first argument? I do see your point, but don't know how to extend that function in the definition.

Comment: @kuba  - The link does explain to me how to use Apply - very powerful. It is very educational and the link on that page by Leonid S. is very helpful too. http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node53.html - post as an answer and I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Take a look at documentation of `Function`, (`Function[{u, v}, u^2 + v^4]`), then `SetDelayed`, `Listable` etc.

Comment: Here is another one: [Can a function be made to accept a variable amount of inputs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6588/5478). If those two linked topics are not exhausting the subject please try to rephrase the question, if they do I will link them as duplicates.

Comment: I do like the 2nd link you gave me slightly better than the 1st and a little easier to understand. However, I like the link inside the first link that points to Leonid's chapter on higher order functions which I found was the easiest to understand. I'd say the 2 links are complementary.

Comment: Ok, since it wasn't a clear case so we don't have to close, the more that m_goldberg summarized it nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your problem here is that you don't fully understand `Function`. The 2nd bullet point under Details in [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) says

> If there are more arguments supplied than [used by] the function, the remaining arguments are ignored.

Let's trace the evaluation of `Function[x, x^2] @@ {12, 2, 4}`

```
Trace[Function[x, x^2] @@ {12, 2, 4}]
```

> `{Function[x, x^2] @@ {12, 2, 4}, Function[x, x^2][12, 2, 4], 12^2, 144}`

We see that `Apply` changes the head `List` to `Function[x, x^2]` just as expected. Then `Function` gets the three arguments 12, 2, 4 and ignores all but the 1st as documented.

Comment: Ah - thank you. So when I do this: Function[x,x^2]@@{{12,2,4}}, I now get {144,4,16}. Not that the double brackets are useful, but confirms what one would expect.