# Is it possible to use PatternTest and Optional value on one Pattern simultaneously?

Tags: pattern-matching, optional-arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Combine Pattern Constraints and Default Values for Function Arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4937/how-to-combine-pattern-constraints-and-default-values-for-function-arguments)

First a simple example: define a function "add" with two arguments, and its second argument should be Positive and have a default value 1.

```
addv1[x_, (y_:1)?Positive] := x + y;
addv2[x_,y?Positive:1] := x + y;
```

these two just don't work as expected.

So is it impossible to use `PatternTest` and `Optional` value on one `Pattern` simultaneously, considering the probability of its default value conflicting with its pattern test?

Comment: Make sure you have a look at my answer. I think the answer is yes.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Wow! I'm reading your book MathProgrammingIntro now. I have learned a lot. Thank you~

Comment: Good to know that it is useful, thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### The syntax

The answer is yes. I use this construct all the time. Here is the form:

```
add[x_, y : (_?Positive) : 1] := x + y;
```

You can test that it passes all the test cases.

#### Sutble behavior to watch out for

There is one additional subtlety associated with this construct: the default value must match the pattern specified for the explicit argument. So, for example, this definition:

```
Clear[addAuto];
addAuto[x_, y : (_?Positive) : Automatic] := x + y;
```

won't work as expected:

```
addAuto[1]

(* addAuto[1] *)
```

because `Automatic` does not match `_?Positive`. But this will:

```
Clear[addAuto];
addAuto[x_, y : (_?Positive | Automatic) : Automatic] := x + y;

addAuto[1]

(* 1+Automatic *)
```

So, make sure that your defualt value matches the explicit arg. pattern. Many, many hours did I waste debugging such cases, more than once. It is not something that first comes to mind. See some more discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401255/pattern-with-optional-argument-in-replacement-rule/6401521#6401521).

Comment: Interesting... wouldn't have thought of that! I'll remove the "no" from my answer. This clearly is the winner :)

Comment: @rm-rf I was thinking that this is a common place, since I personally use this all the time (in particuar, I am sure that I used this form in many of my posts here). Apparently, it seems to be not.

Comment: I'm not surprised that it works though... in fact, immediately after seeing the `FullForm` in the OP's code, I thought: "Hmm, this might work if I simply rearranged to make `Pattern` the  first object inside `Optional`" (which is what your grouping does), but then I saw the docs for the error messages and dismissed it without trying =)

Comment: @rm-rf That seems to be a typical situation with the docs for tricky cases - they are literally correct (for most cases), but they may give an impression that something isn't possible while it really is.

Comment: @rm-rf I added some more stuff here that you may find interesting too.

Comment: Somehow this seems familiar... perhaps we've had this conversation before (very likely)? Or do you discuss this in your book? I seem to have mentioned this fact to the OP in the duplicate, but it is missing in the accepted answer... Either way, I completely forgot about the duplicate that Mr.Wizard dug up and looking at my answer there and here, it seems like I'm married to the thought of using `Condition` for such cases =)

Comment: Leonid, I closed this question as a duplicate but as usual your answer goes beyond mine.  In fact I made the mistake you warn against in it (though honestly I was aware of the situation, I just failed to point it out).  I encourage you to post in that thread.  If not, may I have permission to include similar content in my answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, please do merge my comment into your answer, and then I will delete mine. I completely forgot about that question.

Comment: Leonid, I think you should leave this answer undeleted.  I've removed my answer from the duplicate instead because the OP changed the example after I pointed it out and so my answer isn't necessary anyway. Mr.Wizard can edit his answer to clarify this subtlety, so that the original has all the bases covered.

Comment: @rm-rf I suggested to delete mainly to have a single place with an exhaustive answer, rather than things scattered over several places. I don't have a strong opinion on the matter, though - can keep it as well.

Comment: I used this construct yesterday, even stopping to check out how it worked when the default argument didn't match the test, and ended up with the same `Alternative` (`None` instead of `Automatic`). Small world

Comment: @Rojo Re: small world - very true.

Comment: @rm-rf Somehow I overlooked your comment above. We might have discussed that indeed - I also have some fading memories of such a discussion. I also have an impression that I already posted some answer before where I stressed this subtlety with default value having to match the explicit pattern, but I don't remember where. Re: `Condition` - I used to use it a lot before, but now I somehow prefer `PatternTest` when possible. Usually, I use `Condition` either when the test condition has to keep the expression being matched unevaluated, or when the condition involves several pattern variables.

Answer (score 7):

The two definitions you used don't work because

- `Optional` cannot be used as the first argument in `PatternTest`, thus ruling out `addv1`. This is mentioned in the documentation for [`General::patop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/General/patop.html):

  > A pattern based on `Optional` cannot be used as the first argument in `PatternTest`, `Condition`, `Repeated`, `RepeatedNull`, or `Optional`, or as the second argument in `Pattern`.
- `Optional` requires a `Blank[]` as the optional object and gives a `General::optb` error otherwise, thus ruling out `addv2`

However, you can still retain the expressiveness of the single line definition that you had hoped would work by using `Condition` instead as:

```
Clear@add
add[x_, y_: 1] /; Positive@y := x + y
```

and it works as expected:

```
add[1]
(* 2 *)

add[1, 2]
(* 3 *)

add[1, a]
(* add[1, a] *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and modification.