# Downvalues vs. Scoping for Functions

Tags: functions, function-construction, pattern-matching, scoping, downvalues

Regarding my [recent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19488/function-argument-to-default-under-certain-condition) on using a default value for a function argument when a pattern was not met yielded some interesting answers, but the general consensus was "Yes this can be done, but there are better options."

Assuming the same conditions that certain function arguments (`rt` and `pt` in this case) should default to zero when less than zero, the three main options are as follows:

**Downvalues:**

```
func[qi_, dei_, b_, dmin_, rt_, pt_, t_] := 
     func[{qi, dei, b, dmin, Max[0, rt], Max[0, pt], t}]

func[{qi_, dei_, b_, dmin_, rt_, pt_, t_}] := (*do stuff*)
```

*Or...*

```
func[qi_, dei_, b_, dmin_, rt_?Negative, pt_, t_] := func[qi, dei, b, dmin, 0, pt, t]
func[qi_, dei_, b_, dmin_, rt_, pt_?Negative, t_] := func[qi, dei, b, dmin, rt, 0, t]

func[qi_, dei_, b_, dmin_, rt_, pt_, t_] :=(*do stuff*)
```

**Scoping:**

```
func[qi_, dei_, b_, dmin_, rt_, pt_, t_] := Module[{rtt = Max[0,rt], ptt = Max[0,pt]},
   (*do stuff with rtt and ptt instead*) ]
```

What are the pros and cons of each function definition? Which is the most efficient?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update my old answer but you'll get more diverse opinions this way anyhow.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No big deal.

Comment: Methink you've lost the braces around some functions'  arguments. I'm not editing your question because you already rolled back one edit. But please recheck

Comment: Your function with `_?Negative` doesn't do what the other does, for instance if you pass `rt=-3; pt=1` it will be evaluated as `rt=0; pt=0` instead of `rt=0;pt=1`

Comment: @belisarius Yep, sorry. Some extra braces made it in there. Edited...

Comment: @ssch, Fixed. That'll teach me to make it up on the fly.

Answer (score 5):

To start the discussion I'll look at timings.  A simplistic test indicates that the DownValues method is somewhat faster, and this agrees with my past experience as well.

```
f1[a_, b_, c_, d_] := f1[{a, b, Max[c, 0], Max[d, 0]}]
f1[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := a + b + c + d

f2[a_, b_, c0_, d0_] := With[{c = Max[c0, 0], d = Max[d0, 0]}, a + b + c + d]

a = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {1*^6, 4}];

f1 @@@ a // Timing // First
f2 @@@ a // Timing // First
```

> 1.872
>
> 2.012

Note that I changed `Module` to `With`.  This should always be faster when it can be used.
For comparison:

```
f2m[a_, b_, c0_, d0_] := Module[{c = Max[c0, 0], d = Max[d0, 0]}, a + b + c + d]

f2m @@@ a // Timing // First
```

> 3.791

Comment: Wow... I wasn't aware that `Module` is so much slower!

Comment: @sebhofer Yes, for *simple* (fast) functions the overhead of `Module` is significant.  `With` does not let you modify variables.  `Block` is faster than `Module` but you have to be very careful to avoid unintended consequences.  You can often combine e.g. `Module` outside the definition of the function and `Block` inside for something reasonably fast.