# How to get Cases to wrap results in an arbitrary head?

Tags: programming, functions, evaluation, pattern-matching

A number of functions provide for results to be wrapped in an arbitrary head.  This is very important in cases where the results should not be evaluated.  Take [`Level`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Level.html) as an example:

```
expr = Hold[{2/2, g[8/4], 1/0}];

Level[expr, {-2}, Hold]
```

> ```
> Hold[1/2, 1/4, 1/0]
> ```

[`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cases.html) however provides no such parameter, causing undesired evaluation:

```
Cases[expr, _Times, 3]
```

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>
>
> ```
> {1, 2, ComplexInfinity}  (* failure *)
> ```

How can this behavior be attained?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best I have is manual RHS holding and `Join`, after which an arbitrary head could be Applied:

```
Join @@ Cases[expr, x : _Times :> Hold[x], 3]
```

> ```
> Hold[2/2, 8/4, 1/0]
> ```

This could be done automatically as follows:

```
makeHeld[(L_ -> R_) | (L_ :> R_)] := L :> HoldComplete[R];
makeHeld[pat_] := x : pat :> HoldComplete[x];

heldCases[expr_, rule_, args___] :=
 Join @@ Cases[Unevaluated @ expr, makeHeld @ rule, args]
```

I am now reasonably happy with this but I still wonder if there is a more elegant or efficient method.

---

For fun here is a one-line definition of `makeHeld` using ["vanishing patterns"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19488/function-argument-to-default-under-certain-condition/19933#19933) and [`Part` properties](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2450/121):

```
makeHeld[(L_ -> R_) | (L_ :> R_) | L_] := x : L -> HoldComplete[R, x][[{1}]];
```

It's not quite as efficient and clarity suffers so I won't replace the version above with it.

Comment: +1. I don't know why you dislike the code, it looks pretty good to me. Just one thing - I'd use `Cases[Unevaluated[expr], Replace[...],args]`.

Comment: @Leonid I'm glad it looks good.  I guess it just seems like a lot of code for what I think is a rather obvious omission from `Cases` syntax.  `Unevaluated[expr]` does make sense regarding the name `holdCases` but it was my intent instead to implement this as if it was a parameter of `Cases`, just as it is for `Level`, and `Cases` does not have `HoldFirst`.

Comment: @Leonid I changed the code somewhat; I think it's easier to read and a bit more efficient.  Do you agree/confirm?

Comment: +1. Can one also include the arbitrary head to make it more flexible like: `heldCases[expr_, rule_, args___, head_] := 
 Join @@ Cases[expr, makeHeld @ rule, args] /. HoldComplete -> head`

Comment: @RunnyKine Yes, you could, but you should write it `head @@ Join @@ Cases[. . .]`.  I almost did this but I realized it was no shorter to include it as an argument.  (Well, I guess it's one character shorter, but even *I* don't make too much of that.)

Comment: That rewrite is really awesome, such an elegant and  beautiful solution.

Comment: @jVincent Thanks!  It's a bit cleaner now than when I first posted.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The reason I suggested `Unevaluated` is that otherwise the expression will evaluate, once passed to `heldCases`, even when you wrap it in one level of `Unevaluated`, because there is a rewrite step `heldCases` to `Cases`. In other words, when I need to destructure an expression while keeping it unevaluated, I use `Cases[Unevaluated[expr],...]`, while doing the same with `heldCases` as `heldCases[Unevaluated[expr],...` won't work with your current code. Re: rewrite - quite nice, I agree.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Ah, I see.  (How many times must I have said that after reading one of your explanations?)

Comment: Mr.W would you kindly explain how the final pattern works? It seems to have confused the hell out of me. Particularly, what is the purpose of `x`? Thanks.

Comment: @rcollyer `x := godObject["rcollyer", "confusticate"]` -- meet me in chat ;-)