# Syntactic Sugar for TestReports

Tags: timing, testing-and-verification

Seems to me that VerificationTests are a bit verbose:

```
TestReport[{VerificationTest[StringFreeQ["apple", "lp"], True], 
  VerificationTest[StringFreeQ["apple", "a" ~~ __ ~~ "e"], False], 
  VerificationTest[StringFreeQ["apple", "ap"], False], 
  VerificationTest[StringFreeQ["apple", "x"], True], 
  VerificationTest[StringFreeQ["", "asd"], True]}]
```

This was the first obvious thing that I tried:

```
args := {{"apple", "lp"}, {"apple", "a" ~~ __ ~~ "e"}, {"apple", "ap"}, {"apple", "x"}, {"", "asd"}};
results := {True, False, (Pause[2]; False), True, True};

tr = TestReport[
  VerificationTest @@@ Thread[{StringFreeQ @@@ args, results}], 
  TimeConstraint -> Quantity[1, "Seconds"]]
```

But this solution has many problems:

- Timing specs and information aren't enforced and preserved
- Evaluations may leak

*What are some elegant ways to cut down the verbosity here without messing with evaluation mechanics of the arguments to VerificationTest?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make it look somewhat more pleasant by using simple expression parsers. For example, define an auxiliary head `Tests`, as follows:

```
ClearAll[transformTest];
SetAttributes[transformTest, {HoldAll, Listable}];
transformTest[lhs_ -> rhs_] := Hold[VerificationTest[lhs, rhs]];
transformTest[Tests[tests___]] := Thread[transformTest[{tests}], Hold];


ClearAll[Tests];
SetAttributes[Tests, HoldAll];
Tests /: TestReport[t_Tests, args___] :=
  Replace[
    transformTest[t],
    Hold[tests___] :> TestReport[tests, args]
  ];
```

And now you can use the following syntax:

```
TestReport @ Tests[
  StringFreeQ["apple", "lp"] -> True, 
  StringFreeQ["apple", "a" ~~ __ ~~ "e"] -> False,
  StringFreeQ["apple", "ap"] -> False, 
  StringFreeQ["apple", "x"] -> True,
  StringFreeQ["", "asd"] -> True
]
```

which looks a little nicer to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can make your own code work simply enough by controlling evaluating with e.g. [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html)

```
Inactive[TestReport][
  Inactive[VerificationTest] @@@ 
   Thread[{Inactive[StringFreeQ] @@@ args, results}]] // Activate
```

or [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html):

```
Block[{StringFreeQ, VerificationTest, TestReport},
  TestReport[VerificationTest @@@ Thread[{StringFreeQ @@@ args, results}]]
]
```

If writing this myself I would probably use my own [`heldCases`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31755/121) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121):

```
heldCases[
  Thread @ {args, results},
  {{a_, b_}, r_} :>
    VerificationTest[StringFreeQ[a, b], r]
] /. _[x__] :> TestReport[{x}]
```

I prefer Leonid's more general approach however.