# Replace nested external definitions in Compile

Tags: compile

```
f = #^2 &;
Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, f /@ x, 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> 
     True}] // CompilePrint
```

works fine.

```
f = g[#]^2 &;
g = # - 1 &;
Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, f /@ x, 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> 
     True}] // CompilePrint
```

will have `MainEvaluate[ Hold[g][ R1]]`. I guess the automatic replacement will only do such replacement once.

I have found one workaround so far, but it requires listing all the related functions (not necessary in the correct replacement order).

```
ReleaseHold[
  Hold[Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, f /@ x]] //. 
   Flatten[OwnValues /@ Unevaluated@{f, g}]] // CompilePrint
```

Is there a better one without listing `{f, g}`?

Comment: The mechanism used by `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True` seems opaque, that is I cannot find any information about how it is implemented using `Trace`.  Would it be useful to you simply to programmatically extract `f` and `g` from your `Compile` expression for use in your own method?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yeah, if I can programmatically list all the "Global" symbols like `f` inside `Compile` and the derived symbols like `g`, the problem is solved. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Would you like to have all non ``System` `` Symbols or do you prefer to restrict it to ``Global` `` Symbols?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am not sure how to define that, since all temporary variable is unwanted (including param of `Compile` and local variable in `Module` inside compile which has `Global` context)

Comment: Okay.  I'll look at this and try to come up with something useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a proof of concept of the idea of parsing the `Compile` expression, extracting Symbols, finding dependent definitions, and inserting them back into `Compile`.

First a [`HoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html) variation of [`heldCases`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31754/121):

```
makeHeld[(L_ -> R_) | (L_ :> R_)] := L :> HoldComplete[R];
makeHeld[pat_] := x : pat :> HoldComplete[x];

Attributes[heldCases] = {HoldFirst};

heldCases[expr_, rule_, args___] := 
  Join @@ Cases[Unevaluated @ expr, makeHeld @ rule, args]
```

Then the main definition:

```
Attributes[inject] = {HoldFirst};

inject[all : Compile[var_, body_, opts___]] :=
  Complement[
    heldCases[body, s_Symbol /; Context[s] =!= "System`", {-1}, Heads -> True], 
    heldCases[var, s_Symbol | {s_Symbol, __} :> s, {2}]
  ] //
    Apply[FullDefinition] //
    InputForm // ToString // ToHeldExpression //
    Cases[(Set | SetDelayed)[s_Symbol, RHS_] :> (HoldPattern[s] :> RHS)] //
    ( Unevaluated[all] //. # & )
```

Usage :

```
Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, f /@ x, 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}] // inject
```

Replacing `Unevaluated` with `Hold` in the last line of `inject` shows the intermediate output:

> ```
> Hold[Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, ((#1 - 1 &)[#1]^2 &) /@ x, 
>   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]]
> ```

#### Notes

- This is rather verbose for what is conceptually a fairly simple operation.
- I am not happy with the [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html) conversion and back.  Possibly I should have extracted `Symbols` only and used `OwnValues` as you did, but since I resorted to pulling the definitions with `FullDefinition` using that information directly seemed a natural approach.
- The replacements should really only be done on the `body` rather than the entire `Compile`, but the latter was expedient for a proof of concept.