# how to set a function with a default value for some of its variable?

Tags: function-construction

I wonder if there is a way to set a default value in a function definition.

For example, I set up a function

```
f[x_, y_] := (x + y)*2
```

I would like to set the default value of y=5, therefore, even though I only give x equal to 1, the function will return 20.

Comment: `f[x_, y_ : 5] := (x + y)*2`

Comment: See the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html). Btw, any reasonable internet search such as "Mathematica function with default value" will immediately give you the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function argument to default under certain condition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19488/function-argument-to-default-under-certain-condition)