# Syntax error for optional pattern, but only in debugger

Tags: pattern-matching, bugs, syntax, debugging, argument-patterns

This expression ([explained here by Leonid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17712/1517)) evaluates fine unless Evaluation->Debugger is enabled:

```
h[x : (_Integer) : 1] := x
```

> Syntax::sntxf: "x:" cannot be followed by "(_Integer):1".
>   Syntax::tsntxi: "(_Integer):1" is incomplete; more input is needed.
>   Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed .

Strangely it works if the parentheses are removed:

```
h[x : _Integer : 1] := x
```

But both of these fail when debugging:

```
h[x : (_Integer | None) : None] := x
h[x : Alternatives[_Integer, None] : None] := x

(* Workaround: *)
ptn = _Integer | None;
h[x : ptn : None] := x
```

All this was with Mathematica 8.0.4 Linux

What is the debugger up to?

Comment: Seems to work OK in Mma 9.0

Comment: The obligatory question: what version are you running?

Comment: @rcollyer "All this was with Mathematica 8.0.4 Linux" :)

Comment: Yeah, yeah. I should read the whole thing before I comment. I know, I know. :P