# Version inconsistency with optional arguments: what if the default value doesn't match the pattern?

Tags: pattern-matching, core-language, language-design, compatibility, optional-arguments

I just came across some weird behaviour.  Take this function definition:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[vs_List : All] := "match"
```

The default value of `vs` is `All`.  Now think about what `f[]` should return.  Should it evaluate?  You might say *yes*, `vs` will just take the default value.  But you might say, *wait, `All` doesn't even match `_List` so this is nonsense!*

It turns out that different versions behave differently:

Version 9.0.1:

```
{$VersionNumber, $ReleaseNumber}
f[]
(* {9., 1} *)
(* f[] *)
```

Version 10.0.2:

```
{$VersionNumber, $ReleaseNumber}
f[]
(* {10., 2} *)
(* f[] *)
```

Version 10.2.0:

```
{$VersionNumber, $ReleaseNumber}
f[]
(* {10.2, 0} *)
(* "match" *)
```

Version 10.3.1:

```
{$VersionNumber, $ReleaseNumber}
f[]
(* {10.3, 1} *)
(* "match" *)
```

I don't have version 10.1.0 to try with.

**Question:** Is there a bug somewhere?  Which should be the correct behaviour?

---

Ultimately this is of course a [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) situation because the pattern arguably doesn't make sense.  The solution is easy: just use `f[vs : (_List | All) : All] := "match"`.  But I made a mistake and used `_List : All` instead.  Then much later I discovered that my test suite failed in version 10.0 while it was passing in 10.3.

What would be the most user-friendly behaviour in my opinion is for Mathematica to show a warning when it encounters this situation.  Either way, it would be nice to have a mention of this behaviour in the documentation.

Comment: Related: [(4937)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4937/121)

Comment: A really interesting observation!  Version 10.1.0 under Windows also gives `"match"`.

Comment: Also related: [(17707)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17707)

Comment: This change was intentional, and per request of the boss.

Comment: @Daniel  Thanks!  Could we please have this noted in the documentation somewhere, if it is not already?

Comment: @Daniel It would be nice to have a [linter tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) for Mathematica which can catch errors like this and other things that are syntactically valid but likely not what the programmer meant.  I am wondering how hard it would be write one.  One of the difficulties I see is to determine the context of each symbol when importing an `.m` file to be linted. Things like ``Begin["cont`"]`` would have to be parsed manually and applied to subsequent symbols ... `Import[..., {"Package", "HeldExpressions"}]` (understandably) won't be able to get this right.

Comment: I note that you have not Accepted an answer to this question.  As always I in no way wish to force your hand but I am wondering if anything is lacking in my answer?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Update: [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) authoritatively [comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108636/version-inconsistency-with-optional-arguments-what-if-the-default-value-doesnt/108641#comment294016_108636):*

> This change was intentional, and per request of the boss.

---

I can find no mention of this in the documentation, though I am still looking.  My *guess* is that the old behavior was a common source of problems and someone's fix was to implement the new behavior in version 10.1.0.

On the surface at least I like the change as it shortens and simplifies code.  A notable difference is that with the new short scheme the default value is not seen as a valid explicit argument:

```
f[All]

   (* Out:   f[All]   -- 10.1.0 under Windows *)
```

I think this actually may prove useful but I can also imagine it being a new source of confusion.

---

Perhaps this change makes behavior more consistent than it was in the past.
Consider this behavior in older versions (here v7):

```
ClearAll[f, val]

f[vs_List: val] := vs
val = {1, 2, 3};
f[]

   (* Output:   f[]   -- no match *)

ClearAll[f, val]

f[vs : (_List | HoldPattern[val]) : val] := vs
val = "foo";
f[]

   (* Output:   "foo"   *)
```

I find both cases unexpected even if explainable.  The new more permissive behavior makes these cases more similar as both evaluate using the current value of `val`.

---

### Breaking change

There appears to be a serious caveat to this change that I previously failed to note.  In *Mathematica* 7 pattern Symbols are bound to expressions in the default:

```
f[args : {x_, y_} : {1, 2}] := {x, y}

f[]
```

> ```
> {1, 2}
> ```

In version 10.1 this is no longer the case:

```
f[args : {x_, y_} : {1, 2}] := {x, y}

f[]
```

> ```
>  {}
> ```

Reference comments by Itai Seggev in

- [Setting nested optional argument with a default when unpacking from a given Head](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/216851/121)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, `Optional` should just consistently not match when the default value does not match the pattern, period.

Now we have nonsense like this:

```
{}~MatchQ~{Optional[0., 0]}
```

> `False`

You might think this is because `0~MatchQ~0. === False`.

But then why is

```
{}~MatchQ~{Optional[_Real, 0]}
```

> `True`

when `0~MatchQ~_Real` is `False`?

What is the rule here?

---

The situation becomes even more confusing when you start playing with `HoldPattern` (for doing things like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124241/how-to-write-a-heldoptional-variant-of-optional-that-does-not-evaluate-its-s)):

```
G[0] := 0
Gh[0] := h@0
{}~MatchQ~{HoldPattern@Optional[_[_], G[0]]}

{}~MatchQ~{HoldPattern@Optional[_?AtomQ, G[0]]}
{}~MatchQ~{HoldPattern@Optional[0, G[0]]}
{}~MatchQ~{HoldPattern@Optional[_?AtomQ, 0]}

{}~MatchQ~{HoldPattern@Optional[h@_, Gh[0]]}
{}~MatchQ~{HoldPattern@Optional[h@_, h@0]}
```

> True
>
> True
>
> False
>
> True
>
> False
>
> True

I would expect to get `True` for all but the first of these, which is what you get when dropping `HoldPattern`.

---

It feels like it is not well specified what `Optional` should do.

Comment: I don't believe I had read this post until today.  Interesting illustrations.  I think the first case does not match because `0.` is not a pattern?  But I don't know, because as you say it feels like it is not well specified (or at least documented) what it should do here.

Comment: Even though this is a few years late, you can "fix" your first example with `{}~MatchQ~{Optional[o : 0., 0]}`, suggesting that @Mr.Wizard's guess is correct, and an explicit pattern in required