# Functions with both optional arguments and options

Tags: functions, optional-arguments

I have the following codes:

```
plotContour[func_,xRange_:{-2,2},yRange_:{-2,2},opts___]:=
ContourPlot[Re[func[x+I*y]],{x,xRange[[1]],xRange[[2]]},{y,yRange[[1]],yRange[[2]]}, opts]
```

`opts` passes the optioanl arguments like `ContourStyle`, `ImageSize` to the built-in `ContourPlot` function. I have provided default argument values to `xRange` and `yRange`.

But now if I run the following:

```
plotContour[func,ContourStyle->Red]
```

I run into problems because it treats `ContourStyle->Red` as the arguments `xRange`, so I receive errors (`Limiting value ContourStyle in ... is not a machine-sized real number.`)

How should I modify the codes so that it works when I provide optional arguments but skip the arguments with default values?

Comment: I would not thread what is in essence an option (the range to plot over) as a normal function argument in the first place; better use `OptionsPattern` and friends for that.

Comment: I corrected the title.  An "option" is something that looks like `name -> value`.  This is different from an "optional argument" with a default value, which is like `x_ : 1`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As already said in a comment, I would not treat what feels more like an option as an usual argument to the function. Instead you can use `OptionsPattern` and friends.

For a generic function with both own arguments, and potential arguments supplied to functions used within you can use the following design pattern

Define your own function's options in **one** of the following fashions

1. with (protected) symbol (offers the advantage of auto-completion)

   ```
   Protect[xRange, yRange];
   Options[myContourPlot] = {xRange -> {-2, 2}, yRange -> {-2, 2}}
   ```
2. with Strings

   ```
   Options[myContourPlot] = {"xRange" -> {-2, 2}, "yRange" -> {-2, 2}}
   ```

And define your function with

```
myContourPlot[func_, opts : OptionsPattern[{myContourPlot, ContourPlot}]] := 
Module[{x1, x2, y1, y2},
(* read in your options *)
{x1, x2} = OptionValue[xRange] ;
{y1, y2} = OptionValue[yRange];

ContourPlot[Re[func[x + I*y]], {x, x1, x2}, {y, y1, y2}, 
Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Options@ContourPlot]]]
```

Now you can call your function with

```
myContourPlot[Exp, xRange -> {-3, 3}, ContourStyle -> Dashed]
```

or (depending on your choice concerning symbols or strings as option names)

```
myContourPlot[Exp, "xRange" -> {-3, 3}, ContourStyle -> Dashed]
```

Answer (score 13):

This is a common problem when we want to allow both *options* (`name -> value`) and *optional arguments* (arguments that take a default value when omitted) in a function.

The usual solution is **to make the patterns for the optional arguments specific enough that they will not match any options**.

I would do it like this:

```
plotContour[
    func_, 
    xRange : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} : {-2,2} , yRange : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} : {-2,2}, 
    opt : OptionsPattern[] 
  ] := ...
```

Things to pay attention to:

1. When we add a name to a generic [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html), and we also make the corresponding argument optional, we must use two colons like this:

   ```
   name : pattern : defaultValue
   ```
2. Make sure that `defaultValue` itself will match the `pattern` ([related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108636/12))
3. Keep in mind that `OptionsPattern[]` does not only match a *sequence* of options such as `a -> 1, b :> 2`, but also a *list* of options such as `{a -> 1, b :> 2}`.  Thus when making the `pattern` specific, it is not sufficient to require it to be a list. This is why I used `_?NumericQ` instead of `_`.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comment by Sascha, you can use options for the ranges as well as the standard options of ContourPlot, like this:

```
Options[plotContour] = {xRange -> {-2, 2}, yRange -> {-2, 2}}~Join~Options[ContourPlot]; 
plotContour[func_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
Block[{x, y}, 
 With[{xr = {x}~Join~OptionValue[xRange], 
   yr = {y}~Join~OptionValue[yRange]}, 
  ContourPlot[Re[func[x + I*y]], xr, yr, 
   Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ContourPlot]]]]]
```

And then for example:

```
plotContour[#^2 &, ContourStyle -> Red, xRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

Comment: Maybe add `Block[]`

Comment: @Feyre `Block` can be dangerous and should best not be used where a simple `With` is sufficient

Comment: @Sascha sure, but that would be a rewrite of the answer.