# Extra empty lists as function arguments

Tags: function-construction, syntax, options, argument-patterns

Consider the following piece of code:

```
Options[f] = {Option -> True};
f[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{option},
     option = OptionValue@Option;
     If[option, x + 1, x]
]

f[4, {{}, {}}, Option -> True, {}, {}]
f[4, {{}}, {}, {}]
f[4]

5
5
5
```

Why does the function `f` ignore that empty lists and returns the same output as without them instead of returning the same input ? How this behaviour can be avoided ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does the function f ignore that empty lists ...

This is because options can be given in a list, so they can easily be stored and passed around.

```
opts = {PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red};
Plot[Sin[x] + Sin[1.4 x], {x, 0, 10}, Evaluate[opts]]
```

From [`OptionsPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionsPattern.html):

> `OptionsPattern` matches any sequence or nested list of rules, specified with `->` or `:>`.

Thus an empty list will match, and it is equivalent to giving no options.

> How this behaviour can be avoided ?

The best answer really depends on why you want to avoid this, so I am going to stop here.  This behaviour is generally preferable.  It may be inconvenient when you want to [allow both options and optional arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124208/12).