# Why is { } interpreted as an option in my function?

Tags: options, argument-patterns, optional-arguments, pattern-matching

I don't understand the output from:

```
Remove[g];
Options[g] = {"asd" -> 2};
g[a_, Optional[z_?Positive, 1], OptionsPattern[]] := {a, z, OptionValue["asd"]}

g[2, {}, "asd" -> 4]
```

> `{2, 1, 4}`

The documentation of PatternTest says:

> Any result for *test[pval]* other than True is taken to signify failure

but `Positive[{}] =!= True` holds, so it appears that the `{ }` argument is interpreted as an option although the head is not `Rule`. I'm not sure how this should be fixed because I don't understand why it is wrong as it stands. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the expected result? Unevaluated input?

Comment: @kuba I expected `g[2, {}, "asd" -> 4]`

Comment: I am not sure I understand, `{}` fails `Positive` test so optional `1` is used, what is the problem? Sorry if I missed something

Comment: @m_goldberg - I feel like questions where the user misunderstands how *Mathematica* works are specifically on-topic here.  For this question, closing as duplicate of [Extra empty lists as function arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/157048/9490) might be appropriate, so that the next time someone gets confused about this and their search results bring them here, they get directed to a helpful answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extra empty lists as function arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157048/extra-empty-lists-as-function-arguments)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O.k. from the comments and the `OptionsPattern` documentation:

> Any nesting of empty lists will match `OptionsPattern`

I understand now why the pattern matched against my expectation. To make it stop and behave the way I originally had in mind, the last argument (`OptionsPattern[]`) must be replace by

```
e : OptionsPattern[] /; MatchQ[Unevaluated[e], Repeated[_Rule | _RuleDelayed]]
```

After realizing that nested lists are intended as a valid way to specify options, however, it makes more sense to just keep things as in the OP.