# `Optional` with non-empty list requires PatternTest/Condition?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Arbitrary lists are easy to use with `Optional`:

```
a[0]~MatchQ~a[0, Optional[x_List, {}]]
a[0]~MatchQ~a[0, Optional[x:{___}, {}]]
```

> True
>
> True

but

```
a[0]~MatchQ~a[0, Optional[x:{__}, {}]]
```

> False

However, the following, which is semantically equivalent, works:

```
a[0]~MatchQ~a[0, Optional[x_List /; Length[x] > 0, {}]]
```

> True

Would you consider this a bug?

Comment: related: [108636](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108636/5478)