# Basic misunderstanding of Begin

Tags: core-language

In a notebook with a new kernel, execute the following in an `Input` cell:

```
$Context
Begin["Test`"];
$Context
f = x \[Function] x*x;
f[2]
End[];
$Context
f[2]  (* why is this recognized 2nd time?? *)
Test`f[2]
```

The result is as expected (i.e., `f[2]` is unevaluated in the `Global` context).  But now evaluate the same `Inpute` cell, without any changes.  The contexts are reported as before, but this time `f[2]` evaluates to `4` in the `Global` context.  Why?

Comment: The `f[2]` that is followed by the comment returns unevaluated, as it should.  Then, `Test f[2]` returns evaluated, as it should.  What is the issue?

Comment: The second evaluation is different from the first, because ``Global`f`` is already created, so you are assigning to it, instead of ``Test`f``.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two things that influence symbol lookup: `$ContextPath` and `$Context`.  This is described in:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43629/12

In short: `$ContextPath` controls where the system looks for existing symbols. This search is done first.  `$Context` controls where new symbols are created if a name was not found in `$ContextPath` any contexts.

`Begin` changes only `$Context`.  `BeginPackage` changes both `$ContextPath` and `$Context`.

You are only using `Begin`, but not `BeginPackage`.  This means that `$Context` will be set to `` "Test`" `` but `$ContextPath` will stay what it was before.

When you mention a symbol name such as `f`, the first thing Mathematica does is that it looks for it in the contexts contained in `$ContextPath`.  If it is found there, it uses that instance.  This is what happens during the second evaluation: `f` is found in `` Global` ``, so `f` now refers to `` Global`f ``, not `` Test`f ``.

Why does `f` exist in `` Global` ``?  Because you mentioned it when evaluating `f[2]`.  Note the distinction between the fact that a symbol *exists* and that a symbol has associated definitions.  Just evaluating `sym` alone will create that symbol.

Comment: So do you think I should retract a close vote?

Comment: @Kuba As you wish, I am uncertain.  The information there was necessary, but I thought it wasn't quite sufficient ... but then I notice that ilian explained this (very tersely) in this comment, so maybe that would have been enough?

Comment: We can do both, with this answer we can mark this topic as a duplicate in future anyway. In case where original one isn't clearly answering OP.

Comment: While your answer is simple and helpful, the existing situation is complex and confusing.  Iiuc, the behavior I expected matches the current documentation (both online and the documentation that ships with Mma v11) of `$ContextPath`, and indeed was the actual behavior until v6.  Am I correct that due to this behavior change one should effectively never use `Begin .. End` without nesting it in `BeginPackage .. EndPackage`?

Comment: @Alan What does "Iiuc" mean?  Whether you should use `Begin .. End` on their own depends on what you want to achieve ... Any use outside of the standard package structure would be fairly unusual.  But I'm sure that there are some good uses for it I just can't think of one right now (at least not one outside `BeginPackage ...`

Comment: Presumably the behavior change achieved some goal, but I'm not seeing what it is.  One used to be able to safely change context with `Begin .. End`.  Now that seems only to be true relative to an encompassing `BeginPackage .. EndPackage`.
PS "Iiuc" means "If I understand correctly".

Comment: @Alan Maybe there was a good reason. What's more annoying that such small but fundamental changes are made from time to time, yet they are almost never documented.  For any other programming language such a change would be a major point in the release notes.  I see this as a symptom of Wolfram ignoring developers.  Mma is meant to be used interactively from a notebook. There's much less support for writing and distributing packages and there's no help for package authors to ensure compatibility with multiple Mathematica versions. I have 5 versions of Mathematica on my computer just for this.

Comment: @Alan Yet I don't have all of them and I still get surprises due to small but fundamental changes ...  [Some of these changes may be fairly arbitrary ...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108636/version-inconsistency-with-optional-arguments-what-if-the-default-value-doesnt#comment294016_108636)

Comment: @Alan a workaround is to use `f, as it forces f to be in the local context.

Comment: @rcollyer That would be worth an answer if the question weren't closed!  I didn't know this.

Comment: @Szabolcs Here's the relevant [table](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html#14018) in the docs which describes it, and it also discusses how to reference relative contexts, which can be useful. However, as you point out, the last item should read: "a symbol found in the current context path, or local context".