# Optional pattern behaves differently in version 8, 9, and 10+

Tags: pattern-matching, argument-patterns, compatibility

We recently ran into an issue when testing Rubi on older versions. It boils down to this simple example which I didn't dare to simplify further as I cannot test it in versions < 10

```
Test[XXX[expr_, x_], n_Integer : Infinity, OptionsPattern[]] := True /;
  Head[x] === Symbol && n > 0;
Test[___] := False;
XXX[blub, x] // Test
```

The important part is `n` in the pattern and it should say

- `n` is an integer
- `n` is optional an `Infinity` per default
- `n` must be greater zero

Above code gives `False` in versions 8 and 9, but `True` in version 10 and 11. I'm not looking for a workaround, but I'd like to understand why it returns `False` in the older versions.

Maybe someone who still has access can give me some insight.

Comment: In M9 and earlier, the issue is that `Infinity` does not have the head `Integer`. I believe they relaxed the pattern matcher in M10 to allow such patterns.

Comment: I also had this idea, but I was under the impression that the default parameter does not have to have the head from the pattern. E.g. `f[x_Integer: "Error"] := x; f[]` returns "Error" although it also has not the `Integer` head.

Comment: @CarlWoll Ah, OK. Now I understand your comment. You mean in earlier versions the head of the default *must* match if there is a restriction on the pattern, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @CarlWoll That is a completely reasonable explanation. If you post it as answer and someone with 8 or 9 can test it, I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: Here are some support materials for @carl 's point of view. Behavior in v8: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvUzE.png in v9: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpHf4.png in v11.2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoZTr.png

Comment: Just found something interesting. In _v5_ `f[x_head: head@1]` won't be overwritten by `f[x_head: 1]`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo0oy.png Not sure when  this change is introduced.

Answer (score 9):

In M9 and earlier, the default value must match any pattern restrictions. In your example, the head of the default is not [`Integer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integer), and so the default value could never be triggered. In either 10.2 or 10.3 the pattern matcher was relaxed so that the default value no longer needed to match pattern restrictions.

Comment: +1.  The original behaviour and changes are discussed in [(108636)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108636/142), [(4937)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4937/142) and on SE in [(6401255)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6401255/211232).

Comment: @WReach I wonder how you found all these references. I certainly wouldn't.

Comment: @Leonid I remembered that one of these questions existed because it had appeared around the time I had sent feedback to WRI about subtle interactions between facilities with implicit pattern expansion (`Flat`, `OneIdentity`, `Optional`, etc.).  Once I found the first question, the others were linked.

Comment: @WReach I see. That explains it.