# How to split the expressions into four parts include the coefficients of Sin[x], Cos[x], and Exp[x], respectively?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, rule

Given three expressiones as

```
exp1 = x y z*Exp[-t/(x^2 + y^2)] + 
 x/(y + z) Cos[(2 \[Pi])/T t] + (x z)/(y + z) Sin[(2 \[Pi])/T t] + 
 x y z/(x + y + z^2);
exp2 = E^(-(t/(x^2 + y^2))) x y z + (x y z)/(x + y + z^2);
exp3 = (x y z)/(x + y + z^2) + (x Cos[(2 \[Pi] t)/T])/(y + z) + (
   x z Sin[(2 \[Pi] t)/T])/(y + z);
```

How to split it into four parts and get the coefficients of Exp[x_], Sin[x_], Cos[x_], and others?

The expected three result are

```
coeff1 = {xyz, x/(y + z), (x z)/(y + z), x y z/(x + y + z^2)};
coeff2 = {(x y z)/(x + y + z^2), x y z, 0, 0};
coeff3 = {(x y z)/(x + y + z^2), 0, x/(y + z), (x z)/(y + z)};
```

I try

```
split = (a_ + b_*Exp[x_] + c_*Cos[y_] + d_*Sin[z_] -> {a, b, c, d});
exp1/.split
exp2/.split
exp3/.split
```

then the first return is correct as expected, however, the second and third just return what I input.
So how to fix the rule?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

### Explanation

The problem is that pattern matching in Mathematica is purely structural - this means that e.g. the pattern `a_ + b_ * f[_]` will not match `3` (even though you could set `b` to `0` from a mathematical point of view):

```
split = a_ + b_*f[_] :> {a, b};
1 + 3 f[x] /. split
3 /. split
(* {1, 3} *)
(* 3 *)
```

To circumvent this, we can use [`Optional`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html) to indicate that a given part of the pattern can be omitted:

```
split = a_ + HoldPattern@Optional[b_*f[_], 0 f[_]] :> {a, b};
1 + 3 f[x] /. split
3 /. split
(* {1, 3} *)
(* {3, 0} *)
```

Note the use of [`HoldPattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html) to prevent `0 f[_]` from evaluating to `0`. You might ask "why do we even need the second argument of [`Optional`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html)? After all, [`Plus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus.html) has a global [`Default`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html) value of `0` set." However, this does not work:

```
split = a_ + Optional[b_*f[_]] :> {a, b};
1 + 3 f[x] /. split
3 /. split
(* {1, 3} *)
(* 3 *)
```

As far as I can tell, this is because the default value `0` does not match the pattern `b_*f[_]`, which prevents `Optional` from working, as noted by @LeonidShifrin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6401521/3032376):

> This feature of the pattern-matcher is not very widely known, so I
>   will stress it again: the default value for the (optional) pattern
>   `x:ptrn:default` must match `ptrn`. For another example of such behavior,
>   see [this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/2c8d61af757c33c2/) Mathgroup discussion.

Now there was [some change](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108636/version-inconsistency-with-optional-arguments-what-if-the-default-value-doesnt) regarding this, but it does not appear to affect this particular case.

We are also using the (undocumented?) fact that `Optional` will set the values of omitted pattern variables according to the default value:

```
{} /. {Optional[{a_, f[b_]}, {aDef, f[bDef]}]} :> {a, b}
(* {aDef, bDef} *)
```

### Summary

- We need an explicit default value for `Optional` because the pattern `b_ f[_]` does not match the global default `0`
- We need HoldPattern to prevent `0 f[_]` from evaluating
- The value of `b_` is set to `0` in case the default of the `Optional` is used. This is done by matching `b_ f[_]` to the default `0 f[_]`. (So if the default were to be `3 f[_]`, `b` would be `3`)

### Example of question

Armed with this knowledge, it becomes rather<sup>1</sup> straightforward to fix the example of the question:

```
split = (
   a_ +
    HoldPattern@Optional[b_*E^x_, 0*E^_] +
    HoldPattern@Optional[c_*Cos[y_], 0*Cos[_]] + 
    HoldPattern@Optional[d_*Sin[z_], 0*Sin[_]] :> 
     {a, b, c, d}
   );
exp1 /. split
exp2 /. split
exp3 /. split
(* {(x y z)/(x + y + z^2), x y z, x/(y + z), (x z)/(y + z)} *)
(* {(x y z)/(x + y + z^2), x y z, 0, 0} *)
(* {(x y z)/(x + y + z^2), 0, x/(y + z), (x z)/(y + z)} *)
```

<sup>1</sup> There is one small catch: We have to replace `Exp[_]` by `E^_`, since we're using `HoldPattern`, so `Exp[_]` no longer evaluates to `E^_`:

```
Exp[3] // InputForm
(* E^3 *)

E^3 // InputForm
(* E^3 *)

HoldPattern[Exp[3]] // InputForm
(* HoldPattern[Exp[3]] *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your patient explanation. Now I get the point. @Lukas Lang

Answer (score 2):

If you want coefficients of your expression, you'd better use `Coefficient`.

Here are the functions for which you want to determine the coefficients:

```
functions = Cases[{exp1, exp2, exp3}, 
   Exp[x_]|Sin[x_]|Cos[x_], Infinity] // Union
```

> $\{ e^{-\frac{t}{x^2+y^2}}\,, \, \cos\Big[\frac{2\pi t}{T}\Big]\,,\, \sin\Big[\frac{2\pi t}{T}\Big] \}$

Then the coefficients in, say, `exp1` are:

```
Append[Coefficient[exp1, functions], 
  exp1 /. Alternatives @@ functions -> 0]
```

> `{x y z, x/(y + z), (x z)/(y + z), x y z/(x + y + z^2)}`

which matches your `coeff1`.

Change the `exp1` to `exp2` or `exp3` you obtain coefficients of your other expressions.

Comment: Thank you! @QuantumDot. You give a general solution to this question.

Comment: You're welcome.  Don't forget to mark the most useful answer as accepted.