# Is there a shorthand for Optional with Condition?

Tags: function-construction, variable-definitions, conditional, optional-arguments

I have a recursive function that does some work to an object for a `repeated`amount of times.

```
f[h_, repeated_Integer /; repeated >= 0, level_Integer /; level > 0] :=
 Module[{},
  (* Do some stuff to h using level then call foo on h *)
  foo[h, If[level < repeated, f[h, repeated, level + 1], final[h] ]]
]
```

I mostly pass in `1` for the `level` parameter but there are times where I want to start at a different level (aka depth) of `h`. I found I could use the longhand `Optional` to skip passing in `1` for level all the time.

```
Optional[level_Integer /; level > 0 , 1]
```

However, before this I tried using shorthand optional `:` with no success.

```
(level_Integer : 1) /; level > 0
```

and

```
(level_Integer /; level > 0) : 1
```

Both of these give syntax errors.  Is there a way to do this with shorthand optional `:`?

Comment: I though it should have duplicate but I only found this related question about `PatternTest`+`Optional`. [4937](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4937/5478)

Comment: @Kuba I see.  I didn't realise you could condition between the function signature and the SetDelayed.  Thanks.  I think I'll leave this one with longhand if this is the only option.  I think it is cleaner.  However I now can add some parameter interaction test with this new found technique.  Like `g[x_Integer /; x >= 0, y_Integer /; y > 0] /; y > x := {x , y}`. Now that is powerful stuff. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can move condition outside brackets:

```
ClearAll[f]; 
f[x_Integer : 1] /; x >= 0 := {x}
```