# Why is this syntax for patterns with Optional values not supported?

Tags: syntax, argument-patterns, optional-arguments, parsing

I want to express `Optional[PatternTest[Pattern[a,Blank[]],t],1]` concisely.

`a : _?t : 1` is not quite this but works: `Optional[Pattern[a,PatternTest[Blank[],t]],1]`. However I want to get rid of the first `:`.

I started with
`a_?t : 1` which unfortunately turns into `a_?(t : 1)`, i.e. `PatternTest[Pattern[a,Blank[]],Pattern[t,1]]`.

So I tried to go with `(a_?t) : 1` but this gives `Syntax::tsntxi: "(a_?t):1" is incomplete; more input is needed.`.

The only way to that works seems to be to state `Optional` explicitly, e.g. `(a_?t)~Optional~1`.

Why is `(a_?t) : 1` not parsed as `Optional`, or at least as `Pattern` (which is wrong here though) but instead not parsed at all?

---

Aside

Is `: :` a special operator (at least as far as parsing is concerned), like `/: :=`?

Comment: FYI `a :_?t : 1` is not identical to `Optional[PatternTest[Pattern[a, Blank[]], t], 1]`. Check out the `FullForm` of the former. I think the `Infix` is most likely as short as you can get it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  What is it that `a : _?t : 1` doesn't do (regardless of its FullForm)?  I don't see why it's a problem that `PatternTest` is not outside.

Comment: @Szabolcs You are right, it works. But it strikes me as odd that `a_?t : 1` or `(a_?t) : 1` does not.

Comment: Related: [(4937)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4937/121)

Answer (score 14):

The Documentation states (emphasis is mine):

- **`Pattern (:)`**: `s:obj` represents the pattern object `obj`, assigned the **name `s`**.
- **`Optional (:)`**: `p:v` is a pattern object that represents an expression of the **form `p`**, which, if omitted, should be replaced by `v`.

I think that the Documentation page for `Optional` is misleading since it states that the infix operator for `Optional` is `:` what is wrong. I'll show why I think so.

1. First of all when you double click the symbol `:` in the valid pattern object `s_: v` you get selected not the whole pattern as one should expect if the symbol `:` would be the operator between `s_` and `v` (and what happens for the case `s : v` irrespectively of how complicated pattern `v` is), but the construct `_:` is selected! This clearly indicates that `_:` is the actual operator here. So this behavior shows that in this case for `Optional` the corresponding operator is `_:` and not the symbol `:` alone.
2. Citing the Documentation for `Optional`:

   > The form `s_:v` is equivalent to `Optional[s_,v]`. This form is also
   >   equivalent to `s:_:v`. There is no syntactic ambiguity since `s` must
   >   be a symbol in this case.

   So "`s` must be a symbol" what explains the error message `Syntax::tsntxi: "(s_):v:1" is incomplete; more input is needed.` produced for input `(s_) : v : 1`. Note that **the same message is produced for the input `(s_) : v`**. Why this happens? The only explanation again is that for `Optional` the valid operator is `_:` and for `Pattern` is `:`, so this expression should be interpreted as `Pattern[s_, v]` what isn't valid because the name of the pattern must be a symbol (see expanded explanation of how the parser works at the bottom of this answer). Of course the message is vague and doesn't say this explicitly but when we add at the beginning `sym:` we get a valid pattern object `sym : (s_) : v`:

   ```
    sym : (s_) : v // FullForm
   ```

   > ```
   > Optional[Pattern[sym, Pattern[s, Blank[]]], v]
   > ```

   Note that pattern `sym : s_: v` is parsed differently:

   ```
    sym : s_: v // FullForm
   ```

   > ```
   > Pattern[sym, Optional[Pattern[s, Blank[]], v]]
   > ```

   The latter case is consistent with that `_:` is the infix operator for `Optional`. The former suggests that there is a special syntactic form which is parsed as `Optional[Pattern[s, p], v]`: it is the form `s : p : v` where `s` must be a symbol. In this form **two** coupled operators `:` are parsed as a whole for creating this complicated expression which isn't simply `Optional` or `Pattern` but a combination of them both.
3. There is a documented limitation of the parser for `Optional` when it is used without the second argument (i.e. in the meaning of `Default`, emphasis is mine):

   > `Optional[s_h]` represents a function which can be omitted, but which, if present, must have head `h`. **There is no simpler syntactic form for this case.**

   In the view of the previous considerations, the *immediately obvious* reason for this limitation is that the operator for `Default` is `_.` and for `Optional` is `_:`, hence the forms `s_h.` and `s_h:` (as well as `(s_h).` `(s_h):`) can't be used as equivalents for `Optional[s_h]`.

   What isn't obvious is the fact that the two-argument form is nevertheless supported (as another special case):

   ```
   s_h: v // FullForm
   ```

   > ```
   > Optional[Pattern[s, Blank[h]], v]
   > ```

   Note that the form `(s_h) : v` produces the error we already know: `Syntax::tsntxi: "(s_h):v" is incomplete; more input is needed.` The explanation is that there is another special short syntactic form `s_h: v` where the symbol `:` is coupled with preceding symbol `_` and together they are interpreted as the complex construct `Optional[Pattern[s, Blank[h]], v]` which is neither `Optional` nor `Pattern` but a combination of them.

   Note also that when we double-click on the symbol `:` we get selected `s_h:` without `v`. This supports the interpretation that in the input `s_h: v` the symbols `_` and `:` form single syntactic construct which can't be divided into separate operators `_` and `:`. But then why the syntax `s_h:` (short form for `Optional[s_h]`) isn't supported? I think the reason may be simply aesthetic: the *Mathematica* (Wolfram) Language is supposed to be as transparent and readable as possible, and introducing syntax like `s_h:` moves it in the direction of [esoteric programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language) similar to [*regular expressions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) what certainly is undesirable. Personally I find the current situation already unfortunate because the above-mentioned *supported* forms with entirely different meanings are too much similar to each other and hence they are hard to read/interpret.

From my point of view it would be much better to clearly document the actual operators which can be used as short syntactic forms for `Pattern`, `Optional` and `Default` (which correspondingly are `:`, `_:` and `_.`). I see no reasons to introduce the above-mentioned ambiguities and confusion.

---

> Why is `(a_?t) : 1` not parsed as `Optional`, or at least as `Pattern` (which is wrong here though) but instead not parsed at all?

Since we speak about a *short* syntactic input form, we should ask ourselves how the parser handles such special cases? There is a number of such special forms which can be confused with each other (these forms are described in the previous section), so the parser should have simple rules which allow to decide which interpretation it has to accept in this particular case. If it interprets `:` as `Pattern`, then the first argument must be a symbol what isn't the case here, so this interpretation is rejected. The parser doesn't see here the construct `_:`, so it can't interpret it as `Optional` either. Since the symbol `:` is alone, there are no more possible interpretations and the parser reports the syntactic error.

Note that the equivalent syntax `Pattern[a_?t, 1]` is accepted and even evaluated without warnings. The reason is simple: since at the top level it is written in the `FullForm` syntax there is no above-mentioned ambiguity (whether is it `Pattern` or `Optional`?), hence the parser simply takes this expression verbatim. Only when such expression is passed to a function like `ReplaceAll` we get an error message from the evaluator (not from the parser!):

```
1 /. Pattern[a_, x_] :> {a, x}
```

> Pattern::patvar: First element in pattern Pattern[a_,x_] is not a valid pattern name. >>
>
> ```
> 1
> ```