# Span starting from the end

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language, language-design

I could not find something similar.

Given, e.g.

```
lst = Range[10]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
```

the following gives the reverse of `lst` (I know about `Reverse`).

```
lst[[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1]]
(* {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1} *)
```

Why the following does not return the same output?

```
lst[[;; ;; -1]]
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Kuba. This means that I have to provide the starting point to `Span`, right? Otherwise it starts by default from the beginning. Is there any similar concept to Mathematica with Python's slicing? (Thanks for the commenf by the way!)

Comment: What is the difference between Mathematica's `Span` and `Part` compared to Python's slicing? So far you have only shown that Mathematica uses a slightly different syntax.

Comment: @C.E. For instance `lst[::-1]` gives the `lst` reversed without prividing any start/end value.

Comment: It seems that the syntax sugar for reverse is the only difference between the two. Since Span defaults start position to `1` and end position to `All` it cannot use `;; ;; -1` to produce the list reversed. See `;; ;; -1 // InputForm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you evaluate

```
;; ;; -1
```

you get

```
1 ;; All ;; -1
```

This shows that the default starting point is always `1`, regardless of the step size.  Note that `;;` is short for [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html).  Generally, the default for a given argument of `Span` is independent of the other arguments. The default for the first one (beginning) is always `1`, the second one (end) always `All` and the third one (step size) `1`.

`;; ;; -1` will not work because if we start at `1`, we cannot count *downwards* without hitting the boundary of the array.

Comment: It is explicitly documented (emphasis is mine): "`;;;;k` represents a span **from the beginning to the end** in steps of `k`." It is the last point before the "Details" section on the Docs page for [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html).

Comment: ... but the construct `;; ;; -1` is parsed as a whole, and not as a combination of two `Span`s. It can be seen from comparing it with `;; ;; ;; -1` and with `( ;; ) (;; -1)`, and also with `ToExpression[";;;;-1", InputForm, HoldComplete]`. Tangentially related: [(123359)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123391/280).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I did not mean to say that it could not be any other way.