# How to combine those rules into one? Does something like default values exist for patterns?

Tags: pattern-matching, symbolic, expression-manipulation

I am trying to set up a clever set of rules. Say, I am working symbolically with commutators `comm` of matrices, where for instance

```
commRules={
    comm[a_+b_,c_]:>comm[a,c]+comm[b,c],
    comm[ac_?NumericQ * a_+bc_?NumericQ * b_,c_]:>ac*comm[a,c]+bc*comm[b,c],
};
```

Since those two rules are moreorless the same (up to the constants `ac` and `bc`), I am pretty sure one can combine them into one rule. I was thinking of using something like default arguments for functions, as for instance done [in this question and answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4937) - so maybe something along these lines: `comm[ac:(_?NumericQ):1 *a_ + b_,c_]:>ac*comm[a,c]+comm[b,c]`. Of course, this does not work and ends up throwing an error.

Is it possible to combine the `_?NumericQ` tests such that I do not have to hard-code each combination of where the constant factors may appear?

To be very clear, I would like to have a SINGLE rule `commRule` that does e.g. do the follwing

```
comm[a+b,c]/.commRule
comm[2*a+b,c]/.commRule
comm[2*a+3*b,4*c]/.commRule
(* comm[a,c]+comm[b,c] *)
(* 2*comm[a,c]+comm[b,c] *)
(* 8*comm[a,c]+12*comm[b,c] *)
```

** Update **
I also unsuccessfully attempted to use `BlankNullSequence` for this:

```
comm[a + b, c] /. {comm[a_ + fac2___?NumericQ*b_, c] :> comm[a, c] + fac2*comm[b, c]}
(* comm[a + b, c] *)
```

Comment: In order to avoid subtle mistakes it is usually better to use a set of simple rules. E.g. ``commRules={
    comm[a_+b_,c_] :> comm[a,c]+comm[b,c],
    comm[ac_?NumericQ * a_,c_] :> ac*comm[a,c]
};``

Comment: @Shadowray Thanks for your input. You're suggesting the usage of `ReplaceRepeated` in order to split all commutators involving sums into the form `comm[a,c]` and then check for constants, right? This is my current approach actually, but I am curious if a one-liner exists. Can you please be a bit more specific about the subtle mistakes you're referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your three examples are met using [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html) and the existing [`Default`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html) for [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html):

```
commRule = comm[ac_. a_ + bc_. b_, cc_. c_] :> ac*cc*comm[a, c] + bc*cc*comm[b, c];

comm[a + b, c]       /. commRule
comm[2*a + b, c]     /. commRule
comm[2*a + 3*b, 4*c] /. commRule
```

> ```
> comm[a, c] + comm[b, c]
>
> 2 comm[a, c] + comm[b, c]
>
> 8 comm[a, c] + 12 comm[b, c]
> ```

What remains is the additional testing to prevent:

```
comm[x*a + b, c] /. commRule
```

> ```
> comm[b, c] + a comm[x, c]
> ```

With that additional testing:

```
commRule = comm[ac_. a_ + bc_. b_, cc_. c_] /; 
    NumericQ[ac] && NumericQ[bc] && NumericQ[cc] :> 
   ac*cc*comm[a, c] + bc*cc*comm[b, c];
```

Or in a different style, arguably more or less clean:

```
commRule = comm[Optional[ac_?NumericQ] a_ + Optional[bc_?NumericQ] b_, 
    Optional[cc_?NumericQ] c_] :> ac*cc*comm[a, c] + bc*cc*comm[b, c];
```

Now:

```
comm[x*a + b, c] /. commRule
```

> ```
> comm[b, c] + comm[a x, c]
> ```

This might not be what is desired, but it results because the expression `a x` matches the pattern `a_` and a default value of `1` is used for `ac_.` -- you should clarify how this case should be handled.

Comment: Thank you very much, your last version of `commRule` is exactly what I was looking for. That `a x` matches the pattern `a` is absolutely desired in this case, unless neither `a` or `x` have attribute `NumericQ`.

Comment: @Lukas Glad I could help, and thanks for the Accept.