# Meaning of (a : _ : 1)

Tags: pattern-matching, syntax

This is an example from Leonid Shifrin's tutorial:

```
testexpr = Expand[(1 + x)^10]
newexpr = 
 Replace[testexpr, {(a : _ : 1)*x^(y_?EvenQ) :> a*f[x^y], 
   a_ /; FreeQ[a, x] :> f[a]}, 1]
```

Basic question: what does `(a : _ : 1)` mean and do?

Comment: Evaluating `FullForm[Hold[a : _ : 1]]` might be instructive.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't clear on that it is the same as (a_:1)... but why two different syntaxes?

Comment: The core syntax is the colon, which is another way to spell `Pattern`.  The Blank without preceding colon is a convenience that allows omitting parentheses when the low precedence of the colon would otherwise require them.

Comment: Related: [(4937)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4937/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you evaluate `HoldForm@FullForm[a : _ : 1]` you get `Optional[Pattern[a,Blank[]],1]`.  This is a pattern object that will will be named `a` for later use and will be replaced by `1` if missing.

```
f[x] /. f[(a : _ : 1)] -> g[a]  (* g[x] *)
f[] /. f[(a : _ : 1)] -> g[a]  (* g[1] *)
```