# how to work with list as function parameter

Tags: graphics, list-manipulation

I want to output an arrow based on input from user and I tried writing this small function to achieve this:

```
g[{matric}] := 
 For[i = 1, i < Length[mat], i++, 
  Graphics[{Arrow[{{0, 0}, {matric[[1]], matric[[2]]}}]}, Axes -> True, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic]]
```

To call it: `g[mat[[1]]]`

which is not working !!

I want to send array as list for example `{{1,2},{3,4}}` and create its output as arrow but I don't know how to break this list.

The second problem is that I can generate plots using `Apply[f,arg,{1}]` but it gives different plots for different elements in the list,so how can I combine them together in one plot.

I know about `Show` command but I just wanted to know if there is any other way too.

Comment: Your question was hard to read and incorrectly formatted.  I edited it as best I could.  Please familiarize yourself with the editing tools: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Your main issues are your syntax (you've missed the underscore in the function definition) and the use of unnecessary `For` loops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing my best to interpret what you want:

```
g[matrix_] :=
 Graphics[{Arrow[{{0, 0}, #}]}, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic] & /@ matrix

g[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice the pattern `matrix_` on the left-hand side and read [Defining Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html).

To combine these properly simply use a single `Graphics` object with multiple `Arrrow`s:

```
arrows[matrix_] := Arrow[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ matrix

Graphics[
 arrows[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}],
 Axes -> True,
 AspectRatio -> Automatic
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Alchemy as well as wizardry...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: thanks..that exactly what I wanted to know !

Comment: @rafiki I'm glad I could help.  It was not included in your answer but you would do well to learn about patterns and pattern matching.  In this case it may be wise to match a more specific matrix before it is passed to the inner `Function` to make sure that the data given to `Arrow` is not invalid: `arrows[matrix : {{_, _} ..}?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] :=` -- this is a complicated pattern, somewhat intentionally: your effort to understand it may teach you several different aspects of *Mathematica* patterns and programming.  Ask if you need help.  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3146/121

Comment: @Mr.Wizard:thanks for suggestion on optimization...I will code more on it..thanks again :)