# Unique[] in RHS of rule

Tags: replacement, code-review

I have a function, `explicit` that takes dot product of two symbols, and replaces it with repeated dummy indices generated by `Unique[]`.

```
explicit[expr_] := 
  expr //. {Dot[a_, b_] :> (Subscript[a, #] Subscript[b, #]) &[
  Unique[]]};
```

So that if my input is `v.w`, then the output is $v_{$3}w_{$3}$ which is good.

The problem is that if there is a single term multiplying two pairs of dot products, I don't know how to get `Unique[]` to generate a new symbol for each pair.  That is, if I input `c.d e.f` the output is $c_{$3}d_{$3}e_{$3}f_{$3}$, which is bad.  I want $c_{$3}d_{$3}e_{$4}f_{$4}$, with new repeated subscripts. How do I modify my code?

Comment: By the way I don't think you need `ReplaceRepated` here but I left it in my answer since that wasn't the focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You merely need to watch your operator precedence.  Here with brackets to group the RHS properly:

```
explicit[expr_] := 
  expr //. {Dot[a_, b_] :> ((Subscript[a, #] Subscript[b, #]) &[Unique[]])};

explicit[c.d e.f]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How did you know that this was the way to solve the problem?  Even with answers to my other questions on SE, I still don't seem to get it...  it just seems like magic half the time, and I just move on...

Comment: @QuantumDot Well, I know that `Unique[]` needs to be evaluated for each occurrence of `Dot`.  For that I need some head that holds it unevaluated.  You had two in your original code: `RuleDelayed` and `Function`.  `Function` is already being used to distribute a single instance of `Unique[]` to multiple expressions.  That leaves `RuleDelayed`. (Which is exactly the right tool.)  Now I must make sure that `Unique[]` is part of the RHS of `RuleDelayed`.  I can use [these methods](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3146/121) to check how *Mathematica* "sees" this, or just my experience. :-)